# How to find application's path from command line?

Tags: terminal, system-calls

For example, I have `git` installed on my system.
But I don't remember where I installed it, so which command is fit to find this out?

Comment: Heh, heh "`which` command" indeed :)

Comment: Just in case, `command -v` and `which` worked in Linux Alpine 3.16.2 (Docker image). `whereis` and `locate` did not - not installed.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

If it is in your path, then you can run either `type git` or `which git`.  The `which` command has had problems getting the proper path (confusion between environment and dot files).  For `type`, you can get just the path with the `-p` argument.

If it is not in your path, then it's best to look for it with `locate -b git`  It will find anything named 'git'.  It'll be a long list, so might be good to qualify it with `locate -b git | fgrep -w bin`.

Comment: I use `locate` endlessly (it is very fast), but for those unaware of it, `locate` is only as up to date as its most recent database update, which is automatically run daily on my Ubuntu. The *refresh* command is `sudo updatedb` ... Also `locate` has built-in regex capability, so commands like this works: `locate -br "^git$"` ... -b` means restrict the search to just the *basename* ... or without the `-b`, it searches the full pathname .. Also, it only searches paths you have configured it to search.. there is no command-line control of this other than your regex filters.

Comment: Prefer `type` to `which`. [`which` easily gets confused](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10525/how-to-use-which-on-an-aliased-command).

Comment: @Gilles, that's funny for me the behavior is exactly the opposite: `type` is a shell builtin that tells me aliases and such, and `which` is an external program that shows me the path to an executable... although if there's a builtin that gets in the way that executable won't get called.

Comment: @quodlibetor The problems with `which` are that it doesn't know about shell built-ins and functions (which is relevant when you're wondering what typing the command will do), and it uses a different `$PATH` on some systems.

Answer (score 62):

The [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html) way to do this is `command -v git`.  All UNIX-like systems should support this.

Comment: In `zsh`, this will print `alias ls=...` if `ls` is aliased. IMHO the OP was looking for something to produce `/usr/bin/ls`.

Answer (score 24):

`whereis git` and you get the path to the command.

that is just if the git is in you PATH variable, in case you have installed it not through you package manager, it is more complex and you should use the `find` or `locate` commands.

Comment: Use of `which` is also encouraged.

Comment: @Nikhil `type`, rather, not `which`. See [How to use `which` on an aliased command?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10525)

Answer (score 18):

The other answers here seem to be largely geared towards modern versions of Linux, so if you happen to use `git` on an OS that doesn't have `locate`, `whereis`, `which`, or `apropos` (like Solaris, HPUX, etc), then there is always the old standby `find`.

```
find / -name git
```

One some older versions of the systems listed above, you may need a `-print` option supplied to `find`.

```
find / -name git -print
```

And if you do use `locate`, make sure you run `updatedb` periodically. (`locate.updatedb` on some BSD derivatives)

Comment: For programs in the path, [use `type`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16693/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-from-a-script-whether-software-is-installed); it's reliable and portable (except to 30-year old systems).

Comment: Thanks, @Gilles.  I never knew about `type`. :)  That's definitely going in the repertoire!

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that `find` does a full depth-first search of the file system starting from wherever you root it. So `find / -name git` will traverse your whole system. If you know that the program is on your path you can usually do `IFS=":"; path=$PATH; set $path; for dir in $path; do find $dir -name git; done` , although Unix filesystems are permissive enough that this can break in a variety of ways if have weird characters in your `PATH`.

Comment: Actually the command I gave previously will break your `PATH`, the correct thing (with the same caveats as before) is `IFS=":"; for dir in $PATH; do find "$dir" -name git; done`. Also, to reiterate, this answer should only be used by people who don't have access to `type` or `which` *or* `locate`, ie, almost nobody. @Arcege's answer is correct.

Answer (score 6):

To get the path to the installed program you either use `whereis` or `which`. If you happen to forget it's name, you can use`apropos` with a synonym or description of your utility, e.g. `apropos "version control"` will find `git`. Following that is of course the `whatis` command to briefly summarize the function of a program. This does however not apply to all programs and functions on your system. Try for instance `whatis "the meaning of life, universe and everything"`.