# Finding program name by wildcard pattern

Tags: shell, wildcards, executable, path

I am trying to write a script that will attempt to find if a certain program is installed. Lets say that the program is called, myprog. The problem is that the program can be named in different formats such as, 'prefix-myprog', 'myprog', and 'prefix_myprog'.   If I use:

`which myprog`

then the command line will return the correct location only if it is named EXACTLY, myprog.

Is there a way that I can locate all possible instances with a wildcard of sorts?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to write a script to do that (and if so, what do you have so far/where are you at), or are you looking for something that already does it?

Comment: A simple PHP installer. I am trying to locate if the program is already installed, and if so, where it is at. I can not seem to locate all possible instances by using `which`. I figure that I can always loop through all of the possible choices, but just wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find /bin /sbin /usr -type f | grep -i myprog`

Find all files in directories /bin, /sbin and /usr, then filter on 'myprog'.

`man find`

`man grep`

`apropos myprog` can be useful too.

`man apropos`

or what about `locate -r myprog`?

`man locate`

Comment: don't need grep, find can do searching with wildcards: `find /bin /sbin /usr -name '*myprog'`

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the entries in `$PATH` and expand wildcards in each directory in turn.

```
set -f; IFS=:
for dir in $PATH; do
  ls $dir/*myprog* 2>/dev/null
done
set +f; unset IFS
```

In zsh, this is a lot simpler:

```
ls $path/*myprog*(N)
```

By the way, [avoid `which`, use `type` or `command -v` instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16693/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-from-a-script-whether-software-is-installed).