# how can I use bash as my login shell when my sysadmin refuses to let me change it

Tags: shell, login, profile

The unix sysadmin where I'm working is reluctant to give me access to change my login shell from `ksh` to `bash`.  He has given various excuses, the funniest being that since they write all their scripts for `ksh` they won't work if I try to run them.  I don't know where he gets these ideas, but since I can't convince him, is there any alternative that I have?

(`chsh` is installed on these machines, but we use public/private keypairs for logging in, and I don't have any password, so when `chsh` prompts me for a password I have nothing to give it.  )

Comment: What version of Unix are you using? Are you sure all servers have bash? I learned the hard way in AIX not to change your default shell to bash. If the server does not have bash you can not login.

Comment: I'm at a different job now, but if I recall correctly these were RedHat boxes.  They definitely had bash.  It was an IBM shop, to some extent, so they probably also had some old moldy AIX boxes lying around.  Perhaps that accounts for the sysadmins using ksh.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

When you log in, the file `~/.profile` is read by the login shell (ksh for you). You can instruct that login shell to replace itself by bash. You should take some precautions:

- Only replace the login shell if it's interactive. This is important: otherwise, logging in in graphic mode may not work (this is system-dependent: some but not all systems read `~/.profile` when logging in through xdm or similar), and idioms such as `ssh foo '. ~/.profile; mycommand'` will fail.
- Check that bash is available, so that you can still log in if the executable isn't there for some reason.

You have a choice whether to run bash as a login shell or not. The only major difference in making it a login shell is that it'll load `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`. So if you run bash as login shell, be very careful to have a `~/.bash_profile` or take care not to execute bash recursively from `~/.profile`. There is no real advantage of having `~/.profile` executed by bash rather than ksh, so I'd recommend not doing it.

Also set the `SHELL` environment variable to bash, so that programs such as terminal emulators will invoke that shell.

Here's code to switch to bash. Put it at the end of `~/.profile`.

```
case $- in
  *i*)
    # Interactive session. Try switching to bash.
    if [ -z "$BASH" ]; then # do nothing if running under bash already
      bash=$(command -v bash)
      if [ -x "$bash" ]; then
        export SHELL="$bash"
        exec "$bash"
      fi
    fi
esac
```

Comment: Excellent answer!  stackexchange needs a *Send A Beer* button: this would be a time I'd use it.

Comment: Thanks first and. `.profile` only works for login shell (as OP need). I use Remote Desktop Connection of Windows 10 to login a Linux workstation, then open Terminal in gnome. I want `zsh` while my sysadmin give me `bash`. In this case, I have to add the snippet in `.bashrc` instead of `.profile`.

Answer (score 12):

This is slightly kludgey, but you can cause `bash` to be the shell you're using upon login by creating a `.profile` file in your home directory, containing

```
SHELL=`type -P bash`
exec bash -l
```

This will cause the `ksh` session to be replaced with a `bash` session.  You won't have to type `exit` (or `^D`) twice, as you would if you manually started a new `bash` session every time you logged in.  And typing

```
echo $SHELL
```

will even return the path to `bash`.

Comment: you could of course change $SHELL fairly easily by adding a line to do so before the exec.

Comment: If you want the new shell to also be a login shell you should probably `exec bash -l`.

Comment: This is probably the way I would do it as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  I've incorporated your improvements into my answer.

Comment: One last comment: `type` is [recommended](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16695/9537) over `which`.

Comment: @jw013: good point.... old habits die hard.  I instinctively use `which` and then curse its very existence every time it fails

Comment: Even you can direct run `/bin/bash` if you have linux box and if you have BSD box you can call direct from `/usr/local/bin/bash`

Comment: @seg_fault: sorry, I don't think I followed you.  If you mean that I can just type `/bin/bash` after logging in, then that's exactly the kind of thing I'm trying to avoid.  Mostly because I'll usually forget until `ksh` bites me, and then switching will mean losing the state of my current session.

Comment: @iconoclast i made a lab for you, added jj user and put `ksh` for it.then with `tty2` login with jj.and run `bash`, many of properties of bash are loaded and many of them not loaded, such as `$SHELL` show `/bin/ksh` and `HISTSIZE` shows `1000` and it's related to `bash`.

Comment: I don't get it! Won't `bash` also read `.profile` thus generating an infinite loop? I agree that something along the lines of `exec bash` is what you want, but you need to make sure you do it _only_ to your login ksh so some if-statements are required!

Comment: @user1129682 not if there is `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`

Comment: @UlrichDangel that is a good point - the answer should probably mention that creating either of those files is required to avoid infinite loops using this approach.

Comment: --noprofile to prevent infinite loop. actually removing -l worked for me wtf?

Answer (score 4):

Giles' answer should have the -l flag added when executing bash, so that any login profile scripts will be sourced in the new bash shell.  (For example anything in /etc/profile.d/ on RHEL).  The script should then be:

```
case $- in
  *i*)
    # Interactive session. Try switching to bash.
    if [ -z "$BASH" ]; then # do nothing if running under bash already
      bash=$(command -v bash)
      if [ -x "$bash" ]; then
        export SHELL="$bash"
        exec "$bash" -l
      fi
    fi
esac
```

Comment: Can you explain why you say to add the `-l` option? I have using this for months without it with no issues.

Comment: Can you explain the `-l` option please?

Answer (score 1):

An answer for `csh/tcsh` inspired by the top voted one by @Gilles is

```
if ( ! $?BASH ) then
  setenv BASH `command -v bash`
endif

if ( $?prompt ) then
  if ( -x "$BASH" ) then
    exec "$BASH"
  endif
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Solaris:

```
usermod -s /bin/bash root
```

Comment: Doesn't usermod require admin rights, and the question is " ... when my admin refuses ..." ?