# What's the best distro/shell-agnostic way to set environment variables?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, login

The question says it all. I currently use Arch Linux and the zsh, but I'd like a solution that (at minimum) works both on VTs and in xterms and also (hopefully, preferably) will continue to work if I switch distros or shells.

I've heard wildly disparate answers to this question in different distros' docs. Ubuntu says "use .pam_environment". I think in Arch what they recommend depends on your shell. Currently I put everything in [.profile](https://github.com/strugee/dots/blob/master/.profile) and if a shell doesn't source that for some reason (e.g. bash if .bash_profile exists), I override that by manually sourcing it. But it seems like there must be a better way.

Comment: This has nothing to do with distro and everything to do with shell. Not sure there's a portable way to do it, though.

Comment: Hmm. _Awesome_.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is unfortunately no fully portable location to set environment variables. The two files that come closest are [**`~/.profile`**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085), which is the traditional location and works out of the box on many setups, and **`~/.pam_environment`**, a modern, commonplace but limited alternative.

### What to put in `~/.pam_environment`

The file `~/.pam_environment` is read by all login methods that use [PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_env.html) and that have this file enabled. This covers most Linux systems nowadays.

The major advantage of `~/.pam_environment` is that (when enabled) it is read before the user's shell starts, so it works regardless of the session type, login shell and other complexities. It even works for non-interactive logins such as `su -c somecommand` and `ssh somecommand`.

The major limitation of `~/.pam_environment` is that you can only put simple assignments there, not complex shell syntax. The syntax of this file is as follows.

- Files are parsed line by line.
- Each line must have the form `VAR=VALUE` where VAR consists of letters, digits and underscores. The alternative form `VAR DEFAULT=value` allows expansions of environment variables using `${VAR}` syntax and the special variables `@{HOME}` and `@{SHELL}`.
- `#` starts a comment, it cannot appear in a value.
- If VALUE is surrounded by `"`, then VAR is set to the string between the quotes.
- `\$` or `\@` insert a literal `$` or `@` and long lines can be split by escaping the newline with a `\`.
- If there is a syntax error such as no `=` or unquoted whitespace, the variable is removed from the environment.

So on the upside, `~/.pam_environment` works in a large array of circumstances. On the downside, you cannot use the output of a command (e.g. test if a directory or program is present), and some characters (`#"`, newline) are impossible or troublesome to put in the value.

### What to put in `~/.profile`

This file should have portable (POSIX) sh syntax. Only use ksh or bash extensions (arrays, `[[ … ]]`, etc.) if you know that your system has these shells as `/bin/sh`.

This file may be read by scripts in automated applications, so it should not call programs that produce any output or call `exec`. If you want to do that on text-mode logins, do it only for interactive shells. Example:

```
case $- in *i*)
  # Display a message if I have new mail
  if mail -e; then echo 'You have new mail'; fi
  # If zsh is available, and this looks like a text-mode login, run zsh
  case "`ps $PPID` " in
    *" login "*)
      if type zsh >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then exec zsh; fi;;
  esac
esac
```

This is an example of using `/bin/sh` as your login shell and switching to your favorite shell. See also [how can I use bash as my login shell when my sysadmin refuses to let me change it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46645/how-can-i-use-bash-as-my-login-shell-when-my-sysadmin-refuses-to-let-me-change-i/46682#46682)

### When is `~/.profile` not read on non-graphical login?

Different [login shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/46856#46856) read different files.

#### If your login shell is bash

Bash reads `~/.bash_login` or `~/.bash_profile` if they exist instead of `~/.profile`. Also bash does not read `~/.bashrc` in a login shell even if it is interactive. To never have to remember these quirks again, create a `~/.bash_profile` with the following two lines:

```
. ~/.profile
case $- in *i*) . ~/.bashrc;; esac
```

See also [Which setup files should be used for setting up environment variables with bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/183845/which-setup-files-should-be-used-for-setting-up-environment-variables-with-bash/183956#183956)

#### If your login shell is zsh

Zsh reads `~/.zprofile` and `~/.zlogin`, but not `~/.profile`. Zsh has a different syntax from sh, but can read `~/.profile` in sh emulation mode. You can use this for your `~/.zprofile`:

```
emulate sh -c '. ~/.profile'
```

See also [Zsh not hitting ~/.profile](https://superuser.com/questions/187639/zsh-not-hitting-profile/187673#187673)

#### If your login shell is some other shell

There's not much you can do there, short of using `/bin/sh` as your login shell and your favorite shell (such as fish) as an interactive shell only. That's what I do with zsh. See above for an example of invoking another shell from `~/.profile`.

#### Remote commands

When invoking a remote command without going through an interactive shell, not all shells read a startup file.

Ksh reads the file specified by the `ENV` variable, if you manage to pass it.

Bash reads `~/.bashrc` if it is *not interactive* (!) and its parent process is called `rshd` or `sshd`. So you can start your `~/.bashrc` with

```
if [[ $- != *i* ]]; then
  . ~/.profile
  return
fi
```

Zsh always reads `~/.zshenv` when it starts. Use with caution, since this is read by every single instance of zsh, even when it is a subshell where you've set other variables. If zsh is your login shell and you want to use it to set variables only for remote commands, use a guard: set some variable in `~/.profile`, such as `MY_ENVIRONMENT_HAS_BEEN_SET=yes`, and check this guard before reading `~/.profile`.

```
if [[ -z $MY_ENVIRONMENT_HAS_BEEN_SET ]]; then emulate sh -c '~/.profile'; fi
```

### The case of graphical logins

Many distributions, display managers and desktop environments arrange to run `~/.profile`, either by explicitly sourcing it from the startup scripts or by running a login shell.

Unfortunately, there is no general method to handle distro/DM/DE combinations where `~/.profile` is not read.

If you use a traditional session started by `~/.xsession`, this is the place where you should set your environment variables; do it by sourcing `~/.profile` (i.e. `. ~/.profile`). Note that in some setups, the desktop environment startup scripts will source `~/.profile` again.

Comment: what does `case $- in *i*)` do?

Comment: @qodeninja Executes the following instructions (until the matching `;;` or `esac`) if `$-` matches the pattern `*i*`, i.e. if `$-` contains `i`, i.e. if the shell is interactive.

Comment: `$-` is a string of the currently-set shell options.  (like `set -x`).   `i` means interactive shell.

Comment: Can't you just source a common file, say `~/.config/env`, even without emulation?

Comment: @KevinSuttle Yes, but then the code in this file can't use constructs that behave differently in zsh.

Comment: this answer makes me want to cry

Comment: I don't see the relevance of `/bin/sh` being a ksh/bash shell to whether you can use `[[...]]` in `.profile`. `.profile` is the session customization file for all Bourne-like shells (except `zsh`), so you'd want to use a syntax compatible to all such shells that are ever going to be installed on the system and potentially used as login shell. `/bin/sh` may be bash on your system but you might still want to use yash or dash (or a Bourne shell if your masochist/nostalgic) as your login shell.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That's a purist view. I keep my `.profile` compliant with fairly old Bourne shells, but I recognize that some people just don't care. I have nothing against people assuming that sh = bash for their own files, I only care if they publish `#!/bin/sh` script that use bash features.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there exists no distro and shell agnostic standard how to set environment variables.

The most common and de facto standard seems to be `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`. The second most common seems to be `/etc/environment` and `~/.pam_environment`.

It seems to me that all documentation that I found you also already found. I list them here anyway for the other readers.

- Debian recommends `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` ([link](https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables)).
- Ubuntu recommends `/etc/environment` and `~/.pam_environment` ([link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)).
- Arch Linux mentions, among others, `/etc/profile` and `/etc/environment` ([link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Environment_Variables)).

Bonus: a text questioning the use and/or misuse of `/etc/environment` in debian ([link](http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/nix/distro/debian/deb20-SystemConfiguration/ar01s08.html), last update 2008).

Comment: Regardless of the file you use you would still bump into incompatible syntax between different shells.

Comment: @JosephR. don't most shells keep backwards-compatibility with `sh`? So long as you stick to POSIX, I would have thought you'd be fine...

Comment: AFAIK you can't assign variables in `csh` and friends the POSIX way (you need something like `set` or `setenv`)

Answer (score 1):

If you use [systemd-homed](https://systemd.io/HOME_DIRECTORY/), you should be able to use [`homectl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/homectl.html) to set environment variables for your user account regardless of your shell.
The following command sets the `EDITOR` environment variable this way.

```bsh
homectl update username --setenv=EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following script ~/bin/agnostic_setenv:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set args = ($*)
if ($#args == 1) then
   echo "export $args[1]="
   exit 0
endif

if ($#args == 2) then
   if ("$args[1]" =~ *csh*) then 
      echo "setenv $args[2]"
      exit 0
   else
      echo "export $args[1]=$args[2]"
      exit 0
   endif
endif

echo "setenv $args[2] $args[3]"
```

And in ~/.perl-homedir I use:

```
eval `${HOME}/bin/agnostic_setenv $shell PERL_HOMEDIR 0`
```

A Similiar script for agnostic_unsetenv:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set args = ($*)
if ($#args == 1) then
   echo "export $args[1]"
   exit 0
endif

echo "unsetenv $args[2]"
exit 0
```