# $PATH not modified inside LXDE on Raspbian

Tags: path, raspberry-pi, lxde, raspbian

I have a bin directory in home/pi. This is added to my $PATH when I login (by .profile), but when I go into LXDE and use LXTerminal my bin directory is no longer added to $PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> When  bash  is  invoked  as an *interactive **login** shell*, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the file
>          /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and **~/.profile**, in that
>   order, and reads  and  executes
>          commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When a *login shell* exits, bash reads and executes commands from the files ~/.bash_logout and /etc/bash.bash_logout, if the files
>   exists.
>
> When  an  *interactive shell **that is not a login** shell* is started, bash reads and executes commands from **~/.bashrc**, if that file
>   exists.

"Interactive shells" are ones starting in the foreground on a terminal, but they are not necessarily *login* shells.

> A **login shell** is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or one started with the --login option.

GUI terminals don't do that.

This is why generally, `.profile` sources `.bashrc` -- then `.bashrc` can contain the stuff you want for *all* shells, and `.profile` any additional stuff just for login shells.  Sometimes this is qualified in `.profile` by checking if `$PS1` (the interactive prompt) is defined, so that `.bashrc` only gets included for interactive ones.  One reason for this would be to avoid the use of certain  aliases in non-interactive (e.g., script execution) shells.

So: you could put your $PATH definition in `~/.bashrc`, and make sure it is sourced from `~/.profile` or `~/bash_profile`.

Comment: That works thanks. Now I just have to work out what it all means ! Darn you to Heck Windows(TM), you killed my brain !

Comment: Thx.  I'm dying to know what could have possibly earned me a "-1" here...sigh.

Comment: Are the 3 Bears on here ? I'll up vote you once I get my reputation up to 15 :)

Comment: Please do not recommend setting environment variables in `.bashrc`. It only half works and causes trouble down the line. See my answer.

Comment: @Gilles If the "trouble" is that it's not used by non-interactive shells, I did spell this out and suggest sourcing it from `~/.profile` (which many systems do by default).  WRT to overriding existing env values in a subshell, isn't that the point (as opposed to an undesirable side effect)?

Comment: @goldilocks The most common problem is that applications started from the GUI don't have the environment variable defined. Another problem is when `.profile` runs programs that should be executed once per session (e.g. keyring). Overriding the environment in a subshell is almost always undesirable: if the environment isn't the one that the session started with, there's usually a good reason (and if you want a shell with your default environment, `su - $USER` or `ssh localhost` can do that).

Answer (score 3):

[On most setups, `~/.profile` is read at login time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88201/whats-the-best-distro-shell-agnostic-way-to-set-environment-variables/88266#88266) and this is the usual place to set environment variables. Unfortunately some combinations of distribution, display manager (graphical login method) and desktop environment skip that file. You don't specify which display manager you're using (lxdm?), but it apparently doesn't arrange to read `~/.profile` when the X session starts.

I believe that Raspbian supports `~/.pam_environment`. This file is read by every login method which includes a not-to-antique `pam_env` in the [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules) auth or session section. I believe that is the case on Raspbian (check that `/etc/pam.d/common-session` or `/etc/pam.d/lxdm` contains a line mentioning `pam_env.so`). You can define environment variables in `~/.pam_environment`, but the possibilities are more limited than in `~/.profile`: you can only write `VARIABLE=VALUE`, you can't use other variables or add to the existing value of the variable. So you can't write `PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH` like you would in `~/.profile`, you have to spell it out:

```
PATH=/home/pi/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

I don't recommend setting environment variables in [`.bashrc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085). This would override the existing values whenever you start a subshell, and the variables would only be defined in programs started via a shell in a terminal and [not in programs started directly from the GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343516/emacs-when-run-from-the-applications-menu-via-desktop-setting-doesnt-load-en).

Comment: I think the fact that you can't add to the existing `$PATH` (as defined for the system) makes this method infeasible or undesirable for many users, but it is good to know about. +1

Comment: My hurt brains more now. So much to learn, so little time. I'd +1 you but, you know, stackexchange :(