# Add $HOME/bin to PATH for a single user in Debian Wheezy with LXDE

Tags: debian, path, lxde

In Ubuntu, if $HOME/bin exists, it will be automagically added to PATH, but this doesn't happen in Debian.

How do I permanently add it to PATH for a given user, but only for him, not for all users? I want it to be valid for GUI programs also, not just for the terminal.

**Edit:** To clarify, I use LXDE, and from a login manager, i.e. not `startx`. `.bashrc` does not work for programs I start outside a terminal.

Comment: Note: Since you speak in the third person, there is a possibility that the user is not you. Then it is considered rude to modify his settings yourself (unless he asked it explicitly, of course).

Comment: Don't worry, the user is me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turned out that `lightdm` (the login manager LXDE now uses) does not source `~/.profile`.

What worked for me was creating `~/.xsessionrc`:

```
if [ -d $HOME/bin ]; then
    export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

You can also add this to `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90userbinpath` if you want all user to benefit from this (each user would benefit for his own path) with a system-wide configuration.

Comment: Or you could source the whole .profile file (which might do more than just set $PATH): `if [ -f $HOME/.profile ]; then source $HOME/.profile; fi`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the /etc/profile.

`nano /etc/profile`

There will be two kinds of `PATH`, the path for the root, and the path for normal users, non-root. So you just add to the root or normal users the /$HOME/bin on the final of the line `Ctrl+O` and `Ctrl+X` and there you go :). Remember that you need root to do this operation.

Or, you can go to your home and look at the .profile there.

`cd /home/YOURUSERNAME`
`nano .profile`

In debian it automatically does it too(add the bin to the path). Do a `echo $HOME` to see what home is.

Comment: That would be global for all users, I specifically pointed out "for a single user". Wouldn't it be better to use `~/.profile` instead?

Comment: @sashoalm, edited :)

Comment: OK, but `.profile` doesn't seem to be executed at all. Is it the correct file to use? `echo $PATH` does not show my changes, even from a terminal. I don't have `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`.

Comment: Try to exit your session and make a login again, well I don't know if it is the correct file to use, but every user has one, so it would be the answer for your question...

Comment: Yes, I did that, but it doesn't seem to be read at all. I posted a new question about that - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131320/profile-is-not-sourced-in-debian-wheezy-lxde

Comment: And more, if you are logged as a user the `echo $HOME` would looks like: `/home/yourUserName/`. When you look at the `.profile` at the home directory in the final lines you can see that the script add the /bin if it exists. If its not your case I can paste the code for you.

Comment: I think the problem is I use lxdm - http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90946/9108

Comment: Yea, that's the problem :(

Comment: Try XFCE, it's cool :D

Comment: Advice worthy of a Windows support tech. If all else fails, make clean reinstall ;) But too late, I already solved the problem - http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131327/9108

Comment: Congrats hehe ;)

Answer (score -1):

In your ~/.bashrc file add the following line:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

Save it and then source the file to take effect.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

You can check then by running

```
echo $PATH
```

For running GUI programs from Run command window (Alt + F2) create a new empty .xsession file in your home directory and add these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

Save it and reload your LXDE session. I have tested by moving xterm in $HOME/bin directory and call it with Alt+F2 and in started successfully.

Comment: This will work for a X session/GUI programs, not just for terminal, right?

Comment: This will work for both cases GUI and terminal.

Comment: OK, I thought GUI programs don't inherit from .bashrc, unless started from a terminal.

Comment: Beware you could end up adding `$HOME/bin` to the end of $PATH multiple times this way: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124444/how-can-i-cleanly-add-to-path/

Comment: OK, .bashrc doesn't work - it seems to work only for programs I start from `xterm`, but not for programs I start using "Alt+F2", i.e. from LXDE (the DE I use). The DE uses a login manager, not startx.

Comment: Check my updated answer for running programs using Alt+F2