# .profile is not sourced in Debian Wheezy LXDE

Tags: profile, lxde

I add `$HOME/bin` to `$PATH` from `~/.profile`. However, it seems it is not sourced during login. I use a login manager - `lxdm` I think, and not `startx`. I know this matters as to which scripts are executed.

To illustrate, see how the `$HOME/bin` is added after I explicitly source `~/.profile`. But shouldn't it have been sourced during the graphical login?

```
sashoalm@aspire:~$ echo $PATH 
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
sashoalm@aspire:~$ source ~/.profile 
sashoalm@aspire:~$ echo $PATH 
/home/sashoalm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
sashoalm@aspire:~$
```

Comment: Have you tried adding it to /etc/profile?

Comment: I don't want it to be global for all users, just for a single user.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> But shouldn't it have been sourced during the graphical login?

There's a minor debate about that on which some graphical logins take an unusual stance...

> I add $HOME/bin to $PATH from ~/.profile. However, it seems it is not sourced during login. I use a login manager - lxdm I think

Correct.  Most DM's do read `~/.profile` when you log in.  However, they must do this explicitly, since `~/.profile` is traditionally sourced by *login shells* and a DM (GUI login) is not a shell!

Which is the justification I have seen from the **`lightdm`** people for *not* sourcing `~/.profile` explicitly -- because a DM is not a shell.

You can source `~/.profile` yourself from `~/.xsession` -- [see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/what-is-xsession-for/47426#47426).

Comment: Sourcing `~/.profile` from `~/.xsession` probably worked when this answer was written, but it doesn't seem to work anymore. I got it working by sourcing it in `~/.xsessionrc` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Agree with @goldilocks mostely. Just want to add that the script to source `~/.profile` is `~/.xsessionrc`, instead of `~/.xsession`.

Here is the rationale:

```
qxu@debian:/etc/X11/Xsession.d$ cat 40x11-common_xsessionrc
# This file is sourced by Xsession(5), not executed.

#Source user defined xsessionrc (locales and other environment variables)
if [ -r "$USERXSESSIONRC" ]; then
  . "$USERXSESSIONRC"
fi

qxu@debian:/etc/X11$ grep USERXSESSIONRC Xsession
USERXSESSIONRC=$HOME/.xsessionrc
```

Answer (score 2):

If bash is your login shell, then it will try `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` and `~/.profile` in this order. It will however **stop** at the first one it finds.

If your `~/.profile` is not sourced, then it means you have either one of the other two (possibly both) in your `HOME` directory. You should check which one, then place the new `PATH` statement in the first one.

Comment: While that's a possible reason, those files did not exist in my system (I had checked even before asking).

Answer (score 1):

> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.
>   After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`,
>   `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and
>   executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

So, when `~/.bash_profile` exists, `~/.profile` will never be read.

Comment: Yes, but it does not exist in my case.