# Alias from .bash_profile is not reflected across the system

Tags: bash, path, gcc, scientific-linux, profile

I have few path settings and alias in .bash_profile, and I am exporting those.

For example:

```
alias gcc=/abc/def/......./myrtgcc
export gcc
```

And I want use **myrtgcc** to compile C programs either from terminal or from Eclipse using the command `gcc`; I expect the system to run `myrtgcc somfile.c -o output`.

However this is not the case. Even after adding the above alias in `.bash_profile`, and restarting the system ( or using `source .bash_profile` ) the changes are not reflected: If I open the terminal and type `which gcc`, I get `/usr/bin/gcc` and when eclipse uses "GCC" command it again invokes the same `/usr/bin/gcc`.

How do I make **myrtgcc** default across the system, for command **gcc**

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not overly experienced with aliases and path priorities, but it sounds like $PATH is taking precedence over the alias $gcc. Instead of an alias, perhaps a simple shell script in ~/bin and placing that location sooner in the $PATH structure would do the trick...?

Comment: Thanks for the response.
But, I don't think that may be the reason, because If I explicitly execute > source .bash_profile at terminal and query for > which gcc I get output as **/abc/def/......./myrtgcc**
However, if I open another terminal and query which gcc I get **/usr/bin/gcc**.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that `.bash_profile` is ever being sourced automatically?  If you are using, e.g., `lightdm` as your display manager, it does not happen: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131320/profile-is-not-sourced-in-debian-wheezy-lxde/131326#131326 <- applies to `.bash_profile` as well.

Comment: You can't `export` an alias (FWIK); `alias`es are local to the current shell. You can export environment variables only.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting confused by a few things:

1. `which` does not reflect aliases. So when you're trying to check if an alias was made, using `which` won't help you. Run `alias` without arguments instead; it'll show all the aliases in effect. Example:

   > ```
   > anthony@Zia:~$ foo
   > bash: foo: command not found
   > anthony@Zia:~ [$?=127]$ alias foo='echo hi'
   > anthony@Zia:~$ foo
   > hi
   > anthony@Zia:~$ which foo
   > anthony@Zia:~ [$?=1]$
   > ```
2. Aliases affect the shell, not other things. When `make`, `eclipse`, etc. attempt to run `gcc`, shell aliases will not matter. You also can only export variables, not aliases. Here is an example (again with that foo alias) of perl trying to run it:

   > ```
   > anthony@Zia:~$ perl -Mautodie=system -E 'system("foo")'
   > "foo" failed to start: "No such file or directory" at (eval 6) line 12.
   > at -e line 1
   > ```
3. Most things that compile things run `cc`, `c++`, etc., not `gcc`. So even if you had overridden `gcc`, it probably wouldn't have worked.

### So, how to accomplish this?

The best approach is to tell `make`, etc. which compiler to use:

```
make CC=/path/to/myrtgcc target
```

You can also pass that in the environment when running `/.configure` for programs that use autoconf.

The second approach is to create simple shell scripts called `gcc`, `cc`, etc. in (for example) `~/bin` and put that first in your path. The scripts would look something like this:

```shell
#!/bin/sh
exec /path/to/myrtgcc "$@"
```

and you'd put them first in PATH using something like this in your `.bashrc`:

```shell
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this descriptive explanation. This will help.
Could you please tell me what is the effect of "$@" ?
Does it mean that all the shell scripts in location /path/to/myrtgcc will be executed ?

Comment: @VijayRajanna "$@" is to pass along the arguments. So if you invoke `~/bin/cc -c file.c -o file.o`, the arguments are -c, file.c, -o, file.o, and those will all be passed along to `myrtgcc`.

Answer (score 0):

Read your shell documentation. There are two types of profiles. .bash_profile is executed when you are already logged in and do something such as opening a new terminal. The other type of profile is used when you initially log in to the system and, oddly enough, it is called a login profile. To do what you are wanting to do, try putting your stuff into .profile