# Ways to launch a desktop application with environment variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables, .desktop

I have actually one environment variable that is needed by some GUI applications : `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct`. For now I export it in `~/.bashrc`.

When I run `qt5ct` from a terminal, the app sees the environment variable. But **not** when it is run from a desktop file.

So I tried multiple ways, changing the `Exec=` line of the desktop file (launching `qt5ct` show me if the app sees the environment variable):

- `sh -e 'qt5ct'`    : not detecting
- `sh -c 'qt5ct'`    : not detecting
- `sh -a -e 'qt5ct'` : not detecting
- `bash -c 'qt5ct'`  : not detecting

Finally, managed to find a tricky way (in *my* opinion) that works:

- `/usr/bin/env QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct qt5ct` : **detecting**

So my question is : is there any way to export the variable environment `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME` such as I do in `~/.bashrc` ?
Since it takes me time to edit manually desktop entries (and perhaps these will be overwritten automatically by an update of the app ?).

I tried an export in `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, without any change, and I don't have any `~/.xsession`.

P.S.
Sorry if there are English mistakes, and also if the title is not as accurate as my question.

Comment: When you put it in `.profile`, did you log out and back in? `~/.profile` for the desktop environment is loaded during login only.

Comment: Yes, I even rebooted to be sure. The **exported** environment variable - in `~/.profile` - is still not detected by the app (from desktop file).

Comment: Persistent system-wide variables should be put in `/etc/environment` (no export here). Did you try this yet?

Comment: Works ! In `/etc/environment` the variable is correctly detected ! Thanks again for your time. Perhaps you want to publish it as an answer, to gain points ? If no, there is no problem and I can answer this thread to mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System-wide variables my be set in `/etc/environment`. Please be aware that this file does not take variables or shell code but is meant for static variables only, written as:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct
```

Usually `~.profile` *should* be sources for GUI-logins, but it seems that there is a certain argument between maintainers regarding this. See [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131320/) - the general idea behind **not** sourcing `~/.profile` being that originally the file was meant for shell logins and a GUI login is not considered a shell login. So the file not being sourced might be related to your current desktop manager.