# Using alias in another script (ksh)

Tags: scripting, ksh, alias

I'm writing a `ksh` script, and I'd like to use a command define by an alias in my `.profile` file, in my script. I tried this command in the folder containing my script, and it works. However, in my script, I've: `[command] not found`.

How can I solve this? My command just make a `ls` of a repository, then I'm doing in my script:

```
[command]| grep ... | { IFS== read -r var1 x && IFS== read -r var2 x; }
```

Comment: Why are you defining aliases in your `./profile`? Why not `~/.kshrc` which would solve your problem?

Comment: Actually, I'm in a professional service, and I can't do this. I can only use ./profile.

Comment: Then either source your `.profile` from your script, or define the alias in your script or don't use the alias but the actual command. Why in the world can't you use `~/.kshrc`? That makes no sense, if you can use `.profile` you can use `.kshrc`. Aliases have no business being defined in `.profile`.

Comment: @terdon /me shrugs. I use `.profile` to define shell-agnostic things, and then source it. see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88201/whats-the-best-distro-shell-agnostic-way-to-set-environment-variables

Comment: to reiterate some of the sentiment above, using aliases in a script is a bad idea from the get-go. if you know what that alias is running, why don't you do something like this : (say alias is as such "mycmnd=/usr/sbin/grep") in your script you can use MYCOMMAND=/usr/sbin/grep and then everytime you need to use this command, you can reference it by $MYCOMMAND.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use aliases in your scripts. This is a bad idea for exactly this reason. There are various ways to work around this:

- Define the alias within the script itself
- Source the file that contains the alias from the script. Add this line to it:

  ```
  . /home/your_user/.profile
  ```
- Use the command itself instead of the alias. For example, if you have `alias foo="echo bar"`, use `echo bar` in your script instead of `foo`.

As a general rule, it is a bad idea to set aliases in `.profile`. That file is only read by login shells, not interactive ones and not when running scripts. To make your aliases easily accessible you should add them to `$HOME/.kshrc`. The following is from `man ksh`:

> If the shell is invoked by exec(2), and the first character of
>   argument    zero  ($0) is -, then the shell is assumed to be a login
>   shell and commands are read from /etc/profile and then from
>   either .profile in the current directory or $HOME/.profile, if
>   either file exists.  Next, for    interactive shells, commands are
>   read from the file named by performing    parameter  expansion,
>   command substitution, and arithmetic substitution    on the value of
>   the environment variable ENV if the  file  exists.

In other words, login shells read `/etc/profile` and `.profile` while interactive shells (what you get when you open a terminal) read whatever is in the `$ENV` variable or, if that is not defined, `~/.kshrc`. This means that aliases in your `.profile` will only be read when sshing into the machine or otherwise starting a login shell.

Comment: You forgot the "workaround" of using proper _functions_ :-) "For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions." (from the `bash` manual).

Comment: @Kusalananda you would still have to source the file where the function is defined, so that's not an easy solution either.