# Is there a Bash file that will be always sourced in interactive mode no matter if it is login or non-login?

Tags: bash, login, bashrc

As far as I know, the interactive shells may be login or not login, and the start up files for them are different.

- If interactive + login shell → `/etc/profile` then the first readable of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`
- If interactive + non-login shell → `/etc/bash.bashrc` then `~/.bashrc`

I want to set some variables every time I use an interactive shell regardless whether it is a login shell or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best distro/shell-agnostic way to set environment variables?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88201/whats-the-best-distro-shell-agnostic-way-to-set-environment-variables)

Comment: @strugee No, this question isn't about environment variables.

Comment: @Gilles yes, but your answer applies equally well.

Comment: @strugee That's because I went beyond the immediate question and touched on a peripheral topic. One paragraph in one answer doesn't make a duplicate. Questions are only duplicates if they have substantially identical answers, not if one answer happens to contain enough material to answer the second one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there isn't. Yes, this is a design defect.

Use the following content in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -e ~/.profile ]; then . ~/.profile; fi
if [[ -e ~/.bashrc && $- = *i* ]]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
```

Beware that bash has an even weirder quirk: when it is a non-interactive login shell and the parent process is `rshd` or `sshd`, bash sources `~/.bashrc` (but not `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`). So you might want to put this at the top of your `.bashrc`:

```
if [[ $- != *i* ]]; then return; fi
```

See also [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile) and [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/46856#46856)

Comment: Those quirks are for security reasons (don't load unexpected files when running in a security-sensitive setting).

Comment: @vonbrand Er, what? No, these quirks have absolutely nothing to do with security. There are no “unexpected files” involved (except that loading `.bashrc` in a non-interactive setting actually may well count as unexpected), nor any check of any security-sensitive context.

Comment: Has this a method to prevent loops?

Comment: @Braiam What loops?