# PS1 variable no longer shows coloured bash prompt

Tags: bash, profile

I'm running a VPS with Centos 6.5

I've setup `~/.bash_profile` as in the following screenshot:

[image]

It used to give me an output like this:
[image]

Now that I've installed WHM/Cpanel I no longer see coloured prompt.

`echo $PATH` shows:

```
/usr/local/jdk/bin:/home/jay/perl5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/jay/bin
```

How can I fix this? Can anyone help me?

Everything else works according to the configuration. Grep and ls shows coloured outputs.
I need this to work as I find it convenient to quickly spot previous commands and outputs.

Comment: `$PATH` is not a command but an environment variable where are stored directories containing binaries to run directly in the command line (without typing the full path). Type `echo $PATH` to display its value.

Your $PATH variable seems to be OK. and Have nothing to do with your issue.

Comment: Yes Slyx, you are right. I should have pasted the output of "echo $PATH". Wonder, what is wrong then.

Comment: Type `echo $PS1` to see if its value was altered. May be the $PS1 is modified elsewhere before you get the prompt. If so, type `. .bash_profile` to reload it.

Comment: If you are not running a login shell, then your `~/.bash_profile` won't get sourced, only `.bashrc`. How are you starting bash? If you are simply typing `bash` from the command line *and* `PATH` is also set inside your `.bashrc`, then this would explain what you see.

Comment: Spot on! "echo $PS1" shows "\u@\h [\w]#" in the output which is different. I noticed cpanel/whm had made many changes to /etc/bashrc which might be causing system wide changes. In fact they even have comments about issues with their configuration. I've edited the bashrc file and everything is working now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Rather than edit `/etc/bashrc` and give every user the same prompt, you should put your prompt in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Could you move your answer to your question in an answer box below?  This would be so that the answer is separated from the question.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash's management of initialization files is bizarre. In a login shell, bash reads `/etc/profile` and `~/.bash_profile` only. In an interactive non-login shell, bash reads `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` only. (I'm simplifying somewhat, read the manual if you really want the full details.)

To curb the madness, use the following content in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
# Read the shell-agnostic login hook
if [ -e ~/.profile ]; then . ~/.profile; fi
if [[ $- = *i* ]]; then
  # This is an interactive shell, so read bash's interactive login hooks
  # (which bash omits in login shells)
  if [[ -e /etc/bash.bashrc ]]; then . /etc/bash.bashrc; fi
  if [[ -e /etc/bashrc ]]; then . /etc/bashrc; fi
  if [[ -e ~/.bashrc ]]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
fi
```

Put login-time stuff like environment variable definitions (e.g. `PATH`, `EDITOR`) in `~/.profile`. Put interactive stuff like prompt settings and aliases in `~/.bashrc`.

For more information, see [Is there a Bash file that will be always sourced in interactive mode no matter if it is login or non-login?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122187/is-there-a-bash-file-that-will-be-always-sourced-in-interactive-mode-no-matter-i/122188#122188), [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/46856#46856) and [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Gilles. But I found a much simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks mate, I read the manual and found there was this line at the bottom that needed deleting, `if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi` At this moment I've `if [[ -e ~/.bashrc ]]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi` at the top in `~/.bash_profile`. `~/.bashrc` has default values. I've deleted the word "export" and have default `/etc/bashrc` file (deleted any changes I made in that file) and I still have colours. :) Completely missed that last line in `.bash_profile' because of its formatting or may be it wasn't a single line. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Just answering my own question, in case someone else run into the same issue.

You can either assign the PS1 variable in `/etc/bashrc` for all the users or comment out and use `/.bash_profile` for an individual account. In my case `/.bash_profile` was already setup and all I've to do was to disable PS1 in `/etc/bashrc`.

Refer to the following screenshot. After the modification, reboot or ssh again. Notice the comments left by cPanel developers.

[image]

Many thanks to Slyx and everyone for their valuable responses.

Comment: That “simpler solution” is going to land you into similar problems later. Don't set `PS1` in `.profile` or similar. Don't use `export` in `.bashrc` or similar. The fact that the comment author hasn't figured out what's going on should be a sign not to stick to what they're doing.

Comment: Interesting, before trying out my fix, I did edit both files `/.bashrc` and `/.bash_profile` as per your explanation but the result was the same - no colours. `/etc/bashrc` always get the preference. I do not have any `~/.profile` file. Shall I create one and what should I include in it? Thanks.

Comment: If you don't have anything to put in `.profile`, leave it empty. It's for things like environment variables (but you can put them in `~/.pam_environment` as well). Use the `.bash_profile` in my answer, that way `.bashrc` is always read. You can put `. /etc/bashrc` there as well (I didn't include it because that file is distribution-specific).

Comment: Fixing `/etc/bashrc` fixed my issue, thanks!