# Why does cat'ing a file via ssh result in control characters?

Tags: shell, ssh, terminal

I have a device in `/var/iot/data` which I'm trying to get the data from remotely.

On the machine itself:

```
# cat /var/iot/data | xxd -ps -c 32
80de004a030270055678013ac591e5c6abac2185f4319c8088e3
```

That's the correct data.

If I run the same thing remotely, it looks correct:

```
$ ssh -T -x dragino 'cat /var/iot/data | xxd -ps -c 32' 
80de004a030270055678013ac591e5c6abac2185f4319c8088e3
```

But it's actually coming through with a bunch of escape sequences:

```
$ ssh -T -x dragino 'cat /var/iot/data | xxd -ps -c 32' | xxd
00000000: 1b5d 3131 3b23 3138 3464 3666 0738 3064  .]11;#184d6f.80d
00000010: 6530 3034 6130 3330 3237 3030 3535 3637  e004a03027005567
00000020: 3830 3133 6163 3539 3165 3563 3661 6261  8013ac591e5c6aba
00000030: 6332 3138 3566 3433 3139 6338 3038 3865  c2185f4319c8088e
00000040: 330a 1b5d 3131 3b23 3139 3139 3730 07    3..]11;#191970.
```

What is all that `.]11;#184d6f.` at the beginning?

Comment: I've had this exact problem with `echo`, it just adds the \n at the end and I had no idea why, in your case these are actually the control characters before and after, yet the #184d6f and #191970 makes me wonder why there's a hex color representation there, it's not something that bash usually works with.

Comment: Related but not an answer: https://serverfault.com/a/746638/237978

Comment: Do you have a .bashrc on the remote server? That may be generating those strings. What does `ssh -T -x dragino 'cat /dev/null' | xxd show?

Comment: The two commands are not equivalent. Could you also try `ssh -T -x dragino 'cat /var/iot/data' | xxd -ps -c 32` ?  As far as I can see, there is no reason to run `xxd` remotely.

Comment: What shell are you using on the dragino machine?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a very specific, self-caused problem, unlikely to apply to others.

Comment: @GregBell Oh yes, this Q does apply to others, and should _not_ be closed. If you're so embarassed by it (I don't see why), you can ask for it to be anonymized (via the "Contact" link at the bottom of the page).

Comment: @mosvy other SO answers address the solutions to similar problems that have real (not self-inflicted) causes. Thanks for the anonymize tip.

Answer (score 10):

The sequences are

```
OSC 1 1 ; # 1 8 4 d 6 f BEL
OSC 1 1 ; # 1 9 1 9 7 0 BEL
```

which is are [xterm control sequences](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Commands) to request to set the terminal text background color. Probably caused by a badly written shell initialization file which causes these to be output in an attempt to distinguish the output of commands from the shell prompt, but does so unconditionally

Comment: This was it. My fault. Smoking shoe award. I've setup ssh to change my terminal background so I'm always reminded that I'm on a remote machine. Stupid! Will delete the question. Thanks for this decoding Icarus - it's what made the lightbulb turn on.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that you're being bitten by bash's bizarre behavior with respect to [initialization files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files). Bash loads `.bashrc` in two completely different cases:

- If it's an [interactive, non-login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/46856#46856).
- If it's a non-interactive shell spawned by `sshd`.

So when you log in over SSH, bash loads `.bash_profile` if the shell is interactive, and `.bashrc` if it isn't. Passing `-T` to `ssh` doesn't affect that, and it actually doesn't make a difference in your case since SSH only creates a terminal if you don't pass a command or if you pass `-t` to `ssh`.

Your `.bashrc` apparently contains some code that interacts by the terminal by emitting some escape sequences (specifically, [to set the background color](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/535567)). To avoid this causing havoc, don't run anything from `.bashrc` if bash isn't running interactively. [Put this at the top of `.bashrc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122187/is-there-a-bash-file-that-will-be-always-sourced-in-interactive-mode-no-matter-i/122188#122188):

```
if [[ $- != *i* ]]; then return; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I had an function called `ssh` which set terminal background before ssh'ing so that I always know what terminal is remote. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: And the moral of this is not to call it `ssh`, but something else, `rt` for remote terminal, or `term`. I would avoid `gcc` for get copious characters. Changing the behavior of standard commands frequently works out poorly, the classic example being `alias rm="rm -i"`.

Answer (score -1):

The `-T` option for `ssh` will cause the remote SSH server to allocate a virtual terminal for the session and therefore programs (such as the shell) will act accordingly.

For transferring arbitrary data omit the `-T`  option.

Comment: You're thinking of the `-t` option.  The `-T` does the opposite, explicitly disables pseudo-terminal allocation.