# Shell command output not being displayed in tmux status

Tags: tmux

I have the following [status-right](https://github.com/Thermatix/dotfiles/blob/master/tag-tmux/tmux.conf#L110):

```
set -g status-right "#{prefix_highlight}[wifi:#[fg=brightred]#(wifi_status)#[fg=yellow]|#[fg=brightgreen]#{cpu_icon}#[fg=yellow]:#{cpu_percentage}|#{battery_icon}:#{battery_percentage}:#{battery_remain}] %a %h-%d %H:%M:%S#[default]"
```

and in it the custom shell-command [wifi_status](https://github.com/Thermatix/dotfiles/blob/master/tag-zsh/zsh/bin/wifi_status).

which runs a function([wifi_quality](https://github.com/Thermatix/dotfiles/blob/master/tag-zsh/zsh/custom/functions.sh#L3)) that gets the wifi status and then displays it using [spark](https://github.com/holman/spark).

This was working when I had the `wifi_status` file in `/usr/local/bin` but I wanted it in my version control repo for my dotfiles, so I moved it to a bin folder in my `.zsh` folder and added the folder to my path using 
`$HOME/.zsh/bin`. I can use the command in the shell terminal (even in tmux) and it displays the correct output:

```
▁▃▅█
```

But it won't display in the tmux status bar any more.

What's going on?

It's folder in `$PATH`, config was reloaded, it works in terminal, the file has been set to be executable, I don't get it, why is it now not working?

Since it was asked:

I start tmux by typing it into my terminal (`tmux new`).

My OS is OSX.

I'm running xterm2.

My login shell is ZSH with Oh-My-Zsh framework.

My dotfiles are located [here](https://github.com/Thermatix/dotfiles).

Doing the following in tmux command line (prefix)

```
set-environment PATH $PATH
```

sets the `PATH` variable and it shows up when doing `show-environment`.

Copy + pasting `wifi_status` back to the `/usr/local/bin` folder also hasn't fixed the issue (even with a restart of tmux).

Writing the full path to script doesn't help either.

I solved the problem, For some reason my custom functions file wasn't being sourced properly and as a result it couldn't execute. Moving the function into the file solved that and now it's working.

Comment: Where are you setting `PATH`? You say that you “added the folder to my path using  `$HOME/.zsh/bin`, but since this isn't a standard configuration file, if it's being loaded at all, it's being loaded from a standard configuration file. Which one? I suspect that you're setting `PATH` only in your interactive zsh sessions and not in tmux. You need to post enough information about your configuration files to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your [configuration](https://github.com/Thermatix/dotfiles/blob/master/.zshrc), you set several environment variables in `.zshrc`, including `PATH`. Don't do this. The file `.zshrc` is read when you start an interactive shell, so the variables that it sets will only be available in programs started from an interactive shell. They aren't available
in programs that are started in other ways, in particular from a GUI menu.

You didn't say how you start tmux. If you start it without going through an interactive shell (for example from a login-time file, or directly inside a GUI terminal rather than by typing <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> at an interactive prompt), then those environment variables aren't set in the tmux process.

Move your environment variable definitions to a file that's executed at login time. Which file is executed depends on your login shell, and for GUI logins it depends on how your system has set up session startup, which depends on both the distribution and the display manager. Most setups run shell code from `~/.profile` on login, so put your environment variable definitions there.

If your login shell is bash, make sure that you either don't have a `~/.bash_profile` or that it contains the following two lines and nothing more:

```
. ~/.profile
if [[ $- = *i* ]]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
```

If your login shell is zsh, make sure that your `~/.zprofile` contains the following line:

```
emulate sh -c '. ~/.profile'
```

Alternatively, on most systems, you can define environment variables in `~/.pam_environment`. Note that this file has a simple `VARIABLE=VALUE` syntax, without quotes, `$` expansion, etc.

For more details, see [What's the best distro/shell-agnostic way to set environment variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88201/whats-the-best-distro-shell-agnostic-way-to-set-environment-variables)

Comment: I thought my `.zshrc` was was executed when it's a login shell? And I thought Exporting the `$path` was enough to get the value into child shells? As for setting ENV variables, that's always been there.

Comment: @Thermatix `.zshrc` is only executed by interactive shells, not by non-interactive login shells. (Background: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/a/46856). Exporting `PATH` sets the value for child processes, but in your scenario tmux is evidently not a child of an interactive shell (since, experimentally, it didn't inherit from the value of `PATH` that you set in interactive shells).

Comment: Ok, Added a `.zprofile` file and a `.profile` and still, no dice.

Comment: @Thermatix Are you sure you started a new tmux process after logging in, rather than reusing an existing session? You can use `tmux show-environment` (see the manual for options) to check tmux's environment variables.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, still not showing the correct path variable in tmux envs

Comment: @Thermatix Then you didn't set up your login scripts correctly. `.profile` works on most setups; if it isn't working for you, either you have an unusual setup or you made a mistake somewhere. Ask a new question where you explain exactly what distribution you have and how you log in (GUI or text mode? What is your login shell?), and copy-paste the content of your dot files (`.profile`, `.zprofile`, etc.).