# get Cron to run in the same environment as I get with ssh login

Tags: bash, cron, environment-variables, amazon-ec2

I've a script that runs fine when I ssh to my ubuntu EC2 instance and run it (as the user `ubuntu`)

I want this to happen when the server boots, so I added it to cron as:

```
@reboot sleep 10 && /home/ubuntu/start.sh
```

However when cron runs it, the `PATH` is not the same and some commands fail because binaries are not loaded:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

# in start.sh
echo "path $PATH" >> start.logs
# will log 'path /usr/bin:/bin'
```

I've tried to add `source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc` in my `start.sh` script since I believe that's where the `PATH` is built, at least partially, but that doesn't seem to change much:

```
# in start.sh
source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc
echo "path $PATH" >> start.logs
# will still log 'path /usr/bin:/bin'
```

I've also checked that Cron runs as `ubuntu` and not `root`, which seems to be the case since I edited the cron jobs being logged in as `ubuntu`

Is there an easy way to get cron run in the same environment I get after login to my server by ssh?

Comment: Does `/home/ubuntu/start.sh` have a shebang? If so, is it `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`? AFAIK `source` is not a valid synonym in the `dash` shell (and there are likely things in your `.bashrc` that it will barf on as well)

Answer (score 2):

Normally environment variables should be defined in `~/.profile`, or `~/.bash_profile` if this file exists your login shell is bash. So load this file from the cron job.

```
@reboot . ~/.profile; sleep 10 && /home/ubuntu/start.sh
```

`~/.bashrc` is for interactive customizations only, so you shouldn't load it non-interactively and it usually won't work anyway. If you have environment variables definitions in `.bashrc`, fix that mess first.

Another place to set environment variables is `~/.pam_environment`, if you want to the variable to a constant value (you can't run shell commands in this file).

See [What's the best distro/shell-agnostic way to set environment variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88201/whats-the-best-distro-shell-agnostic-way-to-set-environment-variables/88266#88266), [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/46856#46856) and [Is there a ".bashrc" equivalent file read by all shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/is-there-a-bashrc-equivalent-file-read-by-all-shells/3085#3085) for more information on shell startup files.

Comment: Like such answers which get to the root of the problem i.e., fix the .bashrc mess first. Did it in right earnest!

Answer (score 0):

cron typically runs with sh not bash, these have different profiles.

try running the individual cron under bash, if you have a number of custom env vars you can alway env>/file, source /file in the cron.

Comment: thanks for the clue. I'd rather not pass manually environment variables (because I might forget some) and get cron to run with bash. I've added `SHELL=/bin/bash` to my cron file but that doesn't seem to change the result

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue as:

- run `$ crontab -e`, and add before all other lines `SHELL=/bin/bash` This will force cron to use bash. There are [alternatives](https://askubuntu.com/a/540642/545361) if you want to only do that for one command
- my `.bashrc`, which was the default you get on an AWS EC2 ubuntu instance, had those lines:

.

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

so doing `source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc` would do nothing in the cron job. It seems to serve a purpose so I didn't removed it entirely but replaced it by:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
if [ -z ${RUN_BASHRC+x} ]; then
  echo "might return";
else
  case $- in
      *i*) ;;
        *) return;;
  esac
fi
```

which let me set a flag to bypass this early return.

- Finally, for some reasons, the `PATH` was still not updated correctly. I could fix it by doing:

.

```
ADDITIONAL_PATH=$(sudo -Hiu ubuntu env | grep -oP "^PATH=\K.*")
PATH=$ADDITIONAL_PATH:$PATH
```

I'm not 100% sure what that does :) but it at the end I've the same `PATH` I'd have with logging in with ssh.

So finally:

crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
@reboot RUN_BASHRC=1 /home/ubuntu/startup.sh >> /home/ubuntu/cron-startup.logs
```

`~/.bashrc`: the replacement above

`~/start.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ADDITIONAL_PATH=$(sudo -Hiu ubuntu env | grep -oP "^PATH=\K.*")
PATH=$ADDITIONAL_PATH:$PATH
...
```