# Up arrow for history does not work over SSH

Tags: shell, login, command-history

So when ever I use the up arrow it does not show the history of last command but does ^[[A and down ^[[B
I don't know what is this called but also I have $ but running su did not have it.

Using Ubuntu Server 16.04.1

Comment: Is your shell set to bash, or something else? see [Arrow keys, tab-complete not working](http://askubuntu.com/a/325812/178692)

Comment: What is your `$TERM` set to?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

History is not present in all shells. You need to start a shell with history like `bash`. To do so, just type the name of the shell, like

```
bash
```

or the full path of the executable, like

```
/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 5):

It appears that your login shell is `/bin/sh`. On Ubuntu, this is a shell intended for scripting, it doesn't have any comfortable command line edition feature such as history. To get a proper command line shell, change your login shell to bash or zsh:

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

or

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

If that machine has restrictions which prevent you from changing your login shell, you can tell `sh` to execute bash or zsh when logging in. See [how can I use bash as my login shell when my sysadmin refuses to let me change it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46645/how-can-i-use-bash-as-my-login-shell-when-my-sysadmin-refuses-to-let-me-change-i)