# How do I change (permanently) default shell after login on specific TTYn in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, login, tty

I know that the `chsh` command is used to switch login shell for a user between installed shells, but it works *regardless* of where login comes from (tty1, tty2, ssh, ...). What I'd like to achieve is to have e.g. `csh` on logins from tty7 and e.g. `bash` on all other login sources.

Is this doable at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No and yes.

No, the login shell is tied to the user, not to the TTY where the user logs in.  A user can only have one specific login shell.

Yes, the user may, in the login shell's initialization files, start any other program or utility depending on any condition.

For example, a user with `bash` as their current login shell could add something like the following to their `.bash_profile` file to run `csh` when logging in on virtual terminal 7:

```
case $(tty) in
    */tty7) exec csh -l ;;
esac
```

`exec csh -l` would replace the current shell with `csh`, started as a login shell.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, going to check it out - thx!

Comment: omg it worked! btw, names are /dev/tty1 ... tty63 so I've changed pattern after 'in' to *tty7. SO MUCH THANK YOU!

Comment: The pseudo-terminals used by SSH and terminal emulators are `/dev/pts/0`..., the fixed virtual and serial terminals are `tty1`... and `ttyS0`... The numbers of the `pts/N` ones don't really mean anything, they're just allocated so that you get the next free one.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks for the info and for the edit!