# What is the difference between running a executable just by name and by appending a dot /slash before it?

Tags: process, command

This is the output from `ls -all` command :

```
-rwxr----- 1 subhrcho dba  3600 Nov 13 17:26 jdev
-rw-r----- 1 subhrcho dba  1566 Nov 13 17:26 jdev-Darwin.conf
-rw-r----- 1 subhrcho dba   347 Mar  6  2009 jdev-debug.boot
-rw-r----- 1 subhrcho dba   821 Nov 13 17:26 jdev-logging-debug.conf
-rw-r----- 1 subhrcho dba   584 Nov 13 17:26 jdev-logging.conf
-rw-r----- 1 subhrcho dba  4717 Jul 31 16:09 jdev.boot
-rw-r----- 1 subhrcho dba 12877 Nov 13 17:26 jdev.common
-rw-r----- 1 subhrcho dba  5047 Dec  6 01:43 jdev.conf
-rwxr-x--- 1 subhrcho dba 28160 Nov 13 16:28 jdev.exe
-rwxr-x--- 1 subhrcho dba 28672 Nov 13 16:28 jdev64.exe
-rwxr-x--- 1 subhrcho dba 28672 Nov 13 16:28 jdev64W.exe
-rwxr-x--- 1 subhrcho dba 28160 Nov 13 16:28 jdevW.exe
```

Now when I just run `jdev` it runs a different version of [Oracle JDveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/overview/index.html) than when I run it as `./jdev`..Why is it so ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you run an executable file ( or rather in unix/linux world - a file with executable rights/flag on) like so :

`$ ./jdev`

you then mark with `.` that you want to run a file inside your working directory (directory that you are currently in) that is named `jdev` and has executable rights for the user that is launching it (you have to note that it can still be a link to other file, you can check that by typing `ls -l jdev` in the terminal)

( see [file permissions in linux/unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Symbolic_notation) )

When you run it as

`$ jdev`

then most likely there is `jdev` installed somewhere on the system and you have it in `$PATH` ( e.g. `/usr/bin/` or `/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin/` )

As [peterph](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22886/peterph) stated : you can use `which` to to point the executable that is being launched with particular command, e.g.:

```
$ which find
/usr/bin/find
```

Comment: Also not that the `which` utility can tell you what executable will be used if no path is given.

Comment: @peterph Edited my answer.

Comment: It's much better to use `type` to check what is launched by particular command. Cause `which` will show you just a binary somewhere in the $PATH, however it may be aliased to absolutely another binary.

Comment: @rush I has just tried that and it won't work as  you say: `[~] $which zsoelim
/usr/bin/zsoelim
[~] $  type zsoelim
zsoelim is /usr/bin/zsoelim`.  While `zsoelim -> soelim`

Comment: @Patryk I think rush meant the shell aliases/functions, which `which` has no chance of finding, since it is a standalone binary that doesn't have access to the running shell environment (by which I mean aliases and functions, not just the environment variables, some of which are inherited).

Answer (score 9):

If you call a command with no slash in its name in a shell then, it's looked up in the shell aliases, functions and in the list of paths provided in the `$PATH` environment variable. (note that you can have the current working directory (specified as `.` or the empty string) or any relative directory in `$PATH`, but that's not recommended for security reasons).

If there's a slash in the name, then that doesn't happen, the name is taken as a path to execute the command from (though some shells like `zsh` allow aliases or functions to have slashes in their name which would then take precedence).

So, if you want to run a command called `foo` that is in the current working directory, you have to come up with a name that contains a slash. `./foo` is the most obvious. You could also use the full path, or `../dir/foo`...

To know what the shell would run, use the `type` command. **Do not use the `which` command** which generally doesn't do what you think it does and is a heritage from `csh` which is better left alone.

Comment: Why not "which" but "type" ?

Comment: @Geek, That's a FAQ here, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=[which]+type

Comment: did u provide the correct link ?

Comment: That's a search result on this site to prove it's a frequently asked question. Many answers to those questions will tell you why not to use `which`. See for instance http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16693/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-from-a-script-whether-software-is-installed/16695#16695

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use Zsh's built-in 'where' (better than 'which') to see how and in which order aliases, shell built-ins or anything else will be found in order to $PATH ;-)

Here is an example to understand things better, how it is chosen:

```
[ 0:04:08 ] afsin@s15426859:~ % pwd
/home/afsin
[ 0:04:30 ] afsin@s15426859:~ % which who
/usr/bin/who
[ 0:04:47 ] afsin@s15426859:~ % where who
/usr/bin/who
/usr/bin/X11/who
[ 0:05:27 ] afsin@s15426859:~ % echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games:/home/afsin/bin
[ 0:05:31 ] afsin@s15426859:~ % touch who
[ 0:05:40 ] afsin@s15426859:~ % chmod +x who
[ 0:05:47 ] afsin@s15426859:~ % ls -al who
-rwxr-xr-x 1 afsin afsin 0 23. Jan 00:05 who
[ 0:05:50 ] afsin@s15426859:~ % where who
/usr/bin/who
/usr/bin/X11/who
[ 0:05:55 ] afsin@s15426859:~ % export PATH=$PATH:.
[ 0:06:09 ] afsin@s15426859:~ % where who
/usr/bin/who
/usr/bin/X11/who
./who
[ 0:06:14 ] afsin@s15426859:~ % alias who=who
[ 0:06:19 ] afsin@s15426859:~ % where who
who: aliased to who
/usr/bin/who
/usr/bin/X11/who
./who
[ 0:06:22 ] afsin@s15426859:~ % which who
who: aliased to who
[ 0:06:27 ] afsin@s15426859:~ %
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this probably depends on your shell, the rule usually is:

- If you provide a path, either relative or absolute, that path is used. `./jdev` is a relative path, because `.` stands for the current directory (in fact, `ls -all .` would give you the same as `ls -all`). If you do `/usr/bin/tool/`, you are using an absolute path. In these cases, the file pointed to is executed.
- If you do not provide a path, but just a name, the directories in `$PATH` are searched for the tool you're trying to run.

If you have a file in the current directory with the same name as a file in some of the directories in `$PATH`, and you run it by prepending `./` to its name, you will effectively run a different file.

Perhaps another issue is that you were actually expecting `jdev` to run the executable in the current directory. Unless you changed `$PATH` to include `.`, this is not something you should expect at all...

... and it is still a not so good idea to include `.` there, if you do so please at least put it at the end, so that the rest of `$PATH` is always searched first — just imagine that you are on a shared network directory and someone decides to put an evil binary there as `ls`, if `$PATH` starts with `.`, a simple `ls -lah` will be enough to attack your system.

Comment: Your terminology is confusing. `jdev` alone is also a relative path. The rule is: if it doesn't contain a slash, then it's looked up in aliases, functions and `$PATH`, otherwise, it's looked up directly on the file system (though some shells allow aliases or functions with / in their name which would then take precendence).