# Detect init system using the shell

Tags: shell-script, init, portability

This may have more to do with detecting operating systems, but I specifically need the init system currently in use on the system.

Fedora 15 and Ubuntu now use systemd, Ubuntu used  to use Upstart (long time default until 15.04), while others use variations of System V.

I have an application that I am writing to be a cross-platform daemon.  The init scripts are being dynamically generated based on parameters that can be passed in on configure.

What I'd like to do is only generate the script for the particular init system that they are using. This way the install script can be run reasonably without parameters as root and the daemon can be "installed" automagically.

This is what I've come up with:

- Search for systemd, upstart, etc in /bin
- Compare /proc/1/comm to the systemd, upstart, etc
- Ask the user

**What would be the best cross/platform way of doing this?**

Kind of related, **Can I depend on bash to be on the majority of *nix or is it distribution/OS dependent?**

Target platforms:

- Mac OS
- Linux (all distributions)
- BSD (all versions)
- Solaris, Minix, and other *nix

Comment: Just to add my two cents, bash isn't installed by default on FreeBSD.

Comment: @tjameson, did you find a more direct way? I'm looking for the same thing but the answers here are just directions, not direct answers. In particular 1) script locations to search and 2) detecting the init system in effect, in case there are multiple ones installed (bash was answered directly).

Comment: @naxa - Short answer, no. Long answer, you can get pretty far with `ps -p 1 -o command` (prints the path to the current `init`). On Arch Linux and Fedora (IIRC), it's a symlink to the `systemd` binary (probably same on all `systemd` systems). On `upstart`, `init --help` will print usage information, and on my box, `upstart` is mentioned where it says who to email. On FreeBSD (sysV), this will return an error. There may be similar clues on other systems, but since asking this question, I've decided to just create them for all platforms and make separate packages for each one.

Comment: thanks great info! Hopping from that I've learned that `sudo lsof -a -p 1 -d txt` may give even more exact results. `ps` may print an arbitrary name, whereas with `lsof` you will get the real executable path. (See my question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102453/what-does-init-2-mean-in-the-command-column-of-ps )

Comment: My question is not about detecting the init system from bash in order to write a cross-init-system daemon, and the answers do not provide a clear way to determine it because they are targeting specifically a programmatic solution.

Comment: Try and rephrase some more to distance yourself from that other Q. I'm reading them both and don't see how this isn't a dup. I'd hurry since you've already got 1 close, likely to get 4 more quickly.

Comment: None of the answers or comments in the linked question are bash related. The solutions should be applicable to your case as well.

Comment: Wouldn't a `ps -eaf|grep systemd`, ps -eaf | upstart`...accomplish what you're asking? It reads like you're asking how you'd do this from visual inspection. Am I missing it still?

Comment: @slm why did you not talk on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114613 instead? leave other people's questions be next time.

Comment: related https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/09aa79c58f93029a87ed3f4c42c8f04631472575/system/service.py#L383

Comment: @naxa - I don't understand what you're talking about. When I left that comment that Q didn't even exist. Look at the dates!

Comment: @slm [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114613): `2014-02-10 20:08:49Z`. your [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18209/detect-init-system-using-the-shell?noredirect=1#comment177778_18209): `2014-02-10 20:18:59Z`. I think somehow cpburnz ended up talking on this -ie. someone else's- question her/his own question's duplicate flag. it seems like unfortunate to me.

Comment: @naxa - I replied to his comments here, since they were here. That's just how the commenting works. His Q was eventually marked as a dup later on, in March.

Comment: on rpm distros, `rpm --quiet --query systemd`. this avoids the hanky panky involved in looking for a process or pid or symlink.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For the second question, the answer is **no** and you should have a look at [Resources for portable shell programming](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9997/resources-for-portable-shell-programming).

As for the first part - first of all, you certainly have to be careful. I'd say *perform several tests to make sure* - because the fact that someone *does have* systemd (for ex.) installed, does not mean it is actually used as the default `init`. Also, looking at `/proc/1/comm` can be misleading, because some installations of various init programs can automatically make `/sbin/init` a symlink hardlink or even a renamed version of their main program.

Maybe the most useful thing could be to look at the init scripts type - because those are what you'll actually be creating, no matter what runs them.

As a side note, you might also have a look at [OpenRC](http://roy.marples.name/projects/openrc) which aims to provide a structure of init scripts that is compatible with both Linux and BSD systems.

Comment: What do you mean by "look at the init scripts type"? Often different init systems put their scripts/files somewhere besides `/etc/init`, like systemd puts them in `/etc/systemd`. If I was to have my script grok these, it could take a little while. Oh, and thanks for the link BTW for portable shell programming.

Comment: I meant to say that some init implementations can be adjusted to make use of different init scripts' types and locations (like `/etc/rc.d/` or `/etc/init.d/`). And you should properly adjust your program *at installation time* to utilize the structure that is used on the given system.

Comment: So, are you saying that there is no reliable way to detect the init system programmatically? Having the user pass in parameters is certainly safer, but if the user does not pass anything in, what would be the best way to guess?

Comment: I've no idea what will be the best way **for your program** - it all depends on what systems will the program end up running. I haven't used too many distributions, but I was trying to share my observations  to help you. It is a tough piece of scripting you are about to try and I tried to give you some view on the field - you must come to the final answer yourself or wait for more hints.

Comment: Cool, thanks for all your help. You definitely have pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 67):

I've stepped into this problem myself and decided to do some tests. I fully agree with the answer that one should package for each distro separately, but sometimes there are practical issues that prevent that (not least manpower).

So for those that want to "auto-detect" here's what I've found out *on a limited set of distros* (more below):

- You can tell upstart from:

  ```
  [[ `/sbin/init --version` =~ upstart ]] && echo yes || echo no
  ```
- You can tell systemd from:

  ```
  [[ `systemctl` =~ -\.mount ]] && echo yes || echo no
  ```
- You can tell sys-v init from:

  ```
  [[ -f /etc/init.d/cron && ! -h /etc/init.d/cron ]] && echo yes
  ```

Here are my experiments with the following command line:

```
if [[ `/sbin/init --version` =~ upstart ]]; then echo using upstart;
elif [[ `systemctl` =~ -\.mount ]]; then echo using systemd;
elif [[ -f /etc/init.d/cron && ! -h /etc/init.d/cron ]]; then echo using sysv-init;
else echo cannot tell; fi
```

on ec2 instances (I'm including the us-east AMI id):

- ArchLinux: using systemd (since [2012.10.06](https://www.archlinux.org/releng/releases/2012.10.06/))
- CentOS6.4 ami-52009e3b: using upstart
- CentOS7 ami-96a818fe: using systemd
- Debian 6 ami-80e915e9: using sysv-init
- Debian 7.5 ami-2c886c44: using sysv-init
- Debian 7.6 GCE container-vm: using sysv-init
- RHEL 6.5 ami-8d756fe4: using upstart
- SLES 11 ami-e8084981: using sysv-init
- Ubuntu 10.04 ami-6b350a02: using upstart
- Ubuntu 12.04 ami-b08b6cd8: using upstart
- Ubuntu 14.04 ami-a427efcc: using upstart
- Ubuntu 14.10 and younger: using systemd
- AWS linux 2014.3.2 ami-7c807d14: using upstart
- Fedora 19 ami-f525389c: using systemd
- Fedora 20 ami-21362b48: using systemd

Just to be clear: **I am not claiming that this is foolproof!**, it almost certainly isn't. Also note that for convenience I use bash regexp matches, which are not available everywhere. The above is good enough for me right now. However, if you find a distro where it fails, please let me know and I'll try to fix it if there's an EC2 AMI that reproduces the problem...

Comment: According to the systemd documentation ([sd_booted(3)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man3/sd_booted.3.html)), the correct way to check for systemd is to check if the directory `/run/systemd/system` exists.

Comment: I'll add to this detecting `launchd`, the init system on macOS: `[[ $(ps 1) =~ 'launchd' ]] && echo yes || echo no` tested on a MacBookPro, macOS Sierra Version 10.12

Comment: I'd also add busybox: `if [ -h /sbin/init -a $(readlink /sbin/init | grep
busybox | wc -l) -gt 0 ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi`

Comment: Currently on my debian box, /sbin/init --version complais tyhat there is no --version option.

Answer (score 22):

#### Using processes

Looking at the output from a couple of `ps` commands that can detect the various versions of `systemd` & `upstart`, which could be crafted like so:

*upstart*

```
$ ps -eaf|grep '[u]pstart'
root       492     1  0 Jan02 ?        00:00:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
root      1027     1  0 Jan02 ?        00:00:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
```

*systemd*

```
$ ps -eaf|grep '[s]ystemd'
root         1     0  0 07:27 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 20
root       343     1  0 07:28 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root       367     1  0 07:28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
root       607     1  0 07:28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
dbus       615     1  0 07:28 ?        00:00:13 /bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
```

Paying attention to the name of the process that's PID #1 can also potentially shed light on which init system is being used. On Fedora 19 (which uses `systemd`, for example:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 07:27 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 20
```

Notice it isn't `init`. On Ubuntu with Upstart it's still `/sbin/init`.

```
$ ps -efa|grep init
root         1     0  0 Jan02 ?        00:00:03 /sbin/init
```

**NOTE:** But use this with a bit of caution. There isn't anything set in stone that says a particular init system being used on a given distro *has* to have `systemd` as the PID #1.

*generic*

```
$ (ps -eo "ppid,args" 2>/dev/null || echo "ps call error") \
    | awk 'NR==1 || $1==1' | less
 PPID   COMMAND
    1   /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
    1   /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
    1   /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
```

Look at processes with ppid 1 (children of the init process). (Some of the) child process names might point to the init system in use.

#### The filesystem

If you interrogate the `init` executable, you can get some info from it as well. Simply parsing the `--version` output. For example:

*upstart*

```
$ sudo /sbin/init --version
init (upstart 1.5)
Copyright (C) 2012 Scott James Remnant, Canonical Ltd.

This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY
or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

*systemd*

```
$ type init
init is /usr/sbin/init
```

**NOTE:** The fact that `init` is not in its standard location is a bit of a hint/tell. It's always located in `/sbin/init` on sysvinit systems.

*sysvinit*

```
$ type init
init is /sbin/init
```

Also this:

```
$ sudo init --version
init: invalid option -- -
Usage: init 0123456SsQqAaBbCcUu
```

#### Conclusions

So there doesn't appear to be any one way to do it, but you could formulate a suite of checks that would pinpoint which init system you're using with a fairly high degree of confidence.

Comment: How about: `pgrep systemd >/dev/null && echo init system: systemd`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for: some steps to take to try to determine the init system.

Comment: The PID #1 doesn't necessarily be `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd` if systemd is used, it's a false assumption. On my system, for instance, PID #1 is `/sbin/init` (I use systemd). It is distribution dependent.

Comment: On my kubuntu 15.04 installation I appear to both have systemd and sysvinit. Don't know why or what that means, just saying..
`pgrep systemd >/dev/null && echo init system: systemd -> init system: systemd` and `type init -> init is /sbin/init`

Comment: Linux Mint 17, has both systemd and upstart running, so exit status of pgrep alone isn't enough.

Answer (score 17):

Not that efficient but I it seems to work.

```bash
strings /sbin/init | grep -q "/lib/systemd" && echo SYSTEMD
strings /sbin/init | grep -q "sysvinit" && echo SYSVINIT
strings /sbin/init | grep -q "upstart" && echo UPSTART
```

It will print more lines if more than one strings match, which could be translated to "Can't guess". Strings used in grep could be slightly modified but when tested in the following os I always got one line.

- RHEL 6.4  [UPSTART]
- RHEL ES 4 (Nahant Update 7) [SYSVINIT]
- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS [SYSTEMD]
- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS [UPSTART]
- Fedora release 23 (online shell) [SYSTEMD]
- Debian GNU/Linux 7 (online shell) [SYSTEMD]
- Centos 7.6 (VM) [SYSTEMD]

---

A more simplistic approach of the same solution (but it stops at first match)

```bash
strings /sbin/init |
  awk 'match($0, /(upstart|systemd|sysvinit)/) { print toupper(substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH));exit; }'
```

#### Update:

As [KCGD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/551111/kcgd) points out many systems don't come with `strings` installed. So a more portable alternative could be:

```bash
cat /sbin/init | 
  awk 'match($0, /(upstart|systemd|sysvinit)/) { print toupper(substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH));exit; }' 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: nice first answer. welcome to unix.se!

Comment: I just tried this on a Gentoo default docker image with OpenRC installed, and it returned SYSVINIT.    According to https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Comparison_of_init_systems the default for Gentoo is OpenRC, but it appears that OpenRC uses sysvinit.  When I then attempt OpenRC commands I get "You are attempting to run an OpenRC service on a system which openrc did not boot."  Is there a way to distinguish between sysvinit proper and OpenRC using sysvinit?

Comment: +1. That awk command can be simplified to `strings -n7 /sbin/init | awk '/upstart|systemd|sysvinit/ {print;exit}'
`. Or better, on GNU: `grep -aEiom1 'upstart|systemd|sysvinit'`

Comment: That script works well, but many minimalist systems dont come with `strings` installed by default. This command should work with only cat and awk, which are both present by default: `cat /sbin/init | awk 'match($0, /(upstart|systemd|sysvinit)/) { print toupper(substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH));exit; }' 2> /dev/null`

Comment: @KCGD Correct. Updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 12):

Sometimes it's as easy as using `ls` :

```
$ ls -l /sbin/init
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 juin  25 12:04 /sbin/init -> /lib/systemd/systemd
```

I guess if `/sbin/init` is not a symbolic link, you'll have to check further following suggestions in other answers.

Answer (score 5):

I also had this same problem, and did a lot of tests in some RedHat/CentOS/Debian/Ubuntu/Mint machines. This is what I ended up with, with good results.

1. Find the name of the executable with PID 1:

   ```
   ps -p 1
   ```

   If it's systemd or Upstart, problem solved. If it's "init", it may be a symlink or something other than an upfront name. Go ahead.
2. Find the real path for the executable (only work as root):

   ```
   ls -l `which init`
   ```

   If `init` is a symlink to Upstart or systemd, problem solved. Otherwise, it's **almost** certain that you have SysV init. But it can be a misnamed executable. Go ahead.
3. Find the package which provides the executable. Unfortunately, this is distro-dependent:

   ```
   dpkg-query -S (executable real path) # Debian  
   rpm -qf (executable real path) # RedHat
   ```

Then, if you want to script that (the funniest part, IMHO), these are my one-liners (run as root):

```
ls -l $(which $(ps -p 1 o comm)) | awk '{ system("dpkg-query -S "$NF) }' # Debian  

ls -l $(which $(ps -p 1 o comm)) | awk '{ system("rpm -qf "$NF) }' # RedHat
```

Comment: Not all the operating systems specified have dpkg or rpm (this problem isn't specific to just your answer, BTW).

Comment: @toby-speight Yes, sure. Note I stated so in my answer, just to make the limitation clear.

Comment: As for step 3, you could run `init --version` to get the information.

Answer (score 4):

Also inspecting file descriptors can help. And it's from actually running init (Debian stretch currently allow to have more init systems installed) :-)

```
$ ls -l /proc/1/fd |grep systemd
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 srp 14 13:56 25 -> /run/systemd/initctl/fifo
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 srp 14 13:56 6 -> /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd

$ ls -l /proc/1/fd |grep /run/initctl # sysvinit
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 srp 14 14:04 10 -> /run/initctl

$ ls -l /proc/1/fd |grep upstart
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 srp 13 16:09 13 -> /var/log/upstart/mysql.log.1 (delete
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 srp 13 16:09 9 -> /var/log/upstart/dbus.log.1 (deleted)

$ ls -l /proc/1/fd # busybox
total 0
lrwx------    1 root     root          64 Jan  1 00:00 0 -> /dev/console
lrwx------    1 root     root          64 Jan  1 00:00 1 -> /dev/console
lrwx------    1 root     root          64 Jan  1 00:00 2 -> /dev/console
```

Probably safer way to check for busybox would be to `check /proc/1/exe`, as busybox usually uses symlinks:

```
$ ls -l /proc/1/exe 
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          0 Jan  1 00:00 /proc/1/exe -> /bin/busybox
```

So check could be:

```
{ ls -l /proc/1/fd |grep -q systemd && echo "init: systemd"; } || \
{ ls -l /proc/1/fd |grep -q /run/initctl && echo "init: sysvinit"; } || \
{ ls -l /proc/1/fd |grep -q upstart && echo "init: upstart"; } || \
{ ls -l /proc/1/exe |grep -q busybox && echo "init: busybox"; } || \
echo "unknown init"
```

Comment: Also systems with systemd usually have directory `/run/systemd/system`.

Answer (score 3):

1. This is what distro-specific packages are for. There is much more to installing software properly than just detecting the init system. Many distros use SysVinit but not all of them write their init scripts the same way. The proper way to solve this is to include all the different variants and then bundle it up using spec files with distro-specific dependency names for rpm distros, deb files for apt based systems, etc. Almost all distros have some sort of package specification you can write that includes dependencies, scripts, init scripts, etc. Don't re-invent the wheel here.
2. No. Which brings us back to 1. If you need bash it should be a dependency. You can specify this check as part of your configure scripts, but it should also be in the package descriptions.

**Edit:** Use  flags on your configure script such as  `--with upstart` or `--without sysvinit`. Pick a sane default, then the scripts that package your software for other distros can choose to run this with other options.

Comment: Hmph, so it's looking like I can't have a 'one script to rule them all' solution. I've seen a lot of programs that use autoconf or similar to handle cross-platform stuff, but it doesn't seem like it's the right tool for my application. Is maintaining versions for each platform really the only reliable solution?

Comment: One installation script to rule them all is a BadIdea. It ends up failing more places than it works. Autoconf is good as far as it goes. Work hard on keeping your end of the software as generic as possible and include alternate init scripts in your package. Setup package specifications for several major distros. If your software is good you can get other people to help you out with getting it packaged for other systems.

Comment: @tjameson: I just realized I forgot the most important bit. This sort of thing is usually done with switches passed to the configure script. Each distro's build/package routines can call different switches, and your configure/make only has to know what switch it was passed, not detect all the possible software configurations.

Comment: @Caleb- Yeah, I already have that logic in there, but good catch. I was hoping for a way to sniff the init system to use an intelligent guess than a sane default.

Answer (score 3):

On Gentoo, take a look at pid 1:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0   4216   340 ?        Ss    2013   0:57 init [3]
```

If it is `init`, then the init system is `OpenRC`.  If it is `systemd`, then the init system is `systemd`.

You can detect Gentoo with `[ -f /etc/gentoo-release ]`.

Another method on Gentoo is to use `profile-config show`, which will show what default profile is in use.  All of the profiles except the two ending in /systemd use the OpenRC init.  Keep in mind, these are only representative of a default and it is possible that the user has taken steps to override that default and may not be indicative of the init manger actually in use.

Comment: Dumb question, but how do I check for pid 1?

Comment: Use the `p` option (identical to `-p` and `--pid`) to select by PID. The above snippet is actually the output for `ps u --pid 1`.

Comment: Funtoo uses the /etc/gentoo-release file, with the text "Funtoo Linux ver#" where ver# is currently 1.4. It does not have the profile-config command.

Answer (score 3):

For `systemd`:

```
if [[ `systemctl is-system-running` =~ running ]]; then echo using systemd; fi
```

Comment: downvoting because this answer doesn't provide any new or different information compared to the numerous existing answers.

Comment: @jayhendren I don't see this snippet elsewhere. It's not complete in itself, and would probably better stand as a comment against the answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164092/100397 by TvE

Comment: Oh you're right @roaima. It's not exactly the same as the others. I searched the page for a not-too-specific string :)

Comment: This seems to be by far the most correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about other systems then  Debian (wheezy) /or Ubuntu (14.10.) but I test such issues with the plain old `file` command.

```
file /sbin/init
```

give this:

```
/sbin/init: symbolic link to 'upstart'
```

Debian systems with `systemd` (e.g. sid) show this:

```
# file /sbin/init 
/sbin/init: symbolic link to /lib/systemd/systemd
```

Comment: What system did you test it on? There's no such thing as Debian/Ubuntu and this does not work on Debian. Did you try it on Ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry for this confusion, I mean Debian (wheezy) /or Ubuntu (14.10.).

Output on debian:  `file /sbin/init 
/sbin/init: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=0x8c68a736c6a4e6fadf22d5ac9debf11e79c6bdcd, stripped
` means we use SYSV here.
Output for ubuntu is shown in my answer.

Comment: Exactly, so your solution seems to only work if one happens to be using upstart and Ubuntu.

Comment: @terdon: On systems (RHEL, Fedora) running systemd, it returns "symbolic link to...systemd"; on systems (Ubuntu) running upstart it returns "symbolic link to upstart"; on systems (RHEL, Ubuntu, Debian) running SysV init it returns "executable". While that's hardly a comprehensive survey, and this method is clearly not 100% foolproof, it's clearly much closer to "works for at least the major distros" rather than "only upstart and Ubuntu"!

Comment: @psmears if it also works for some systemd systems, that is indeed better (but not mentioned in this answer). I just tested on a Debian running sysvinit, and three Ubuntus (10.04,12.04 and 14.04, all running upstart) and  `file /sbin/init` returned "executable" on all systems. It also returns the same on a CentOS 5.8, a SLES 10, an Ubuntu 8.04, basically every single system I can get my hands on. So, as far as I can tell it doesn't even work for upstart and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

On debian /sbin/init is a symlink to your default init so

```
ls -l /sbin/init
```

will give you the info you're looking for.

```
$ ls -l /sbin/init 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 nov 18 13:15 /sbin/init -> /lib/systemd/systemd
```

Comment: Not so. On Ubuntu 14.04 with Upstart, it's not a symlink.

Comment: Install another init system and check again.

Comment: And which other `init` can I install on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: ...why not sysv or systemd?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 has exactly one provider of `/sbin/init`: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=%2Fsbin%2Finit

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=utopic&arch=amd64&searchon=names&keywords=systemd

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/openrc

Comment: Wrong package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=systemd-sysv, and openrc does not provide `/sbin/init`. And only from 14.10 onwards.

Comment: So you can install only from one repo?! ...that's why ubuntu != debian BTW you can install it I guess http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/amd64/systemd-sysv/download

Comment: Yes, it's unsupported. That's why Ubuntu is Debian-based, but not Debian.

Comment: Ok, BTW there's another reply which deserves a downvote then

Comment: I don't want to downvote, I just want you to specify which version of Debian it is applicable to. (And perhaps rephrase "Debian-based" to "Debian" only, so that it becomes correct.)

Answer (score 2):

Simply greping into the process with PID 1 will tell you:

```
strings /proc/1/exe |grep -q sysvinit
strings /proc/1/exe |grep -q systemd
```

Comment: Not all the OSeS mentioned have a `proc` filesystem...

Answer (score 1):

This is really easy for some init systems. For systemd:

```
test -d /run/systemd/system
```

for upstart:

```
initctl --version | grep -q upstart
```

for anything else, you can just assume based on the distro (launchd on OS X, sysvinit on Debian, OpenRC on Gentoo).

Comment: "assume based on the distro" doesn't work for Debian, where at least three different inits are supported...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bash script to do the detection. It only checks for upstart and systemd at the moment, but should be easy to extend. I've taken this [from code I've contributed to the DisplayLink driver install script](https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/issues/11#issuecomment-193877839).

```
detect_distro()
{
  # init process is pid 1
  INIT=`ls -l /proc/1/exe`
  if [[ $INIT == *"upstart"* ]]; then
    SYSTEMINITDAEMON=upstart
  elif [[ $INIT == *"systemd"* ]]; then
    SYSTEMINITDAEMON=systemd
  elif [[ $INIT == *"/sbin/init"* ]]; then
    INIT=`/sbin/init --version`
    if [[ $INIT == *"upstart"* ]]; then
      SYSTEMINITDAEMON=upstart
    elif [[ $INIT == *"systemd"* ]]; then
      SYSTEMINITDAEMON=systemd
    fi
  fi

  if [ -z "$SYSTEMINITDAEMON" ]; then
    echo "WARNING: Unknown distribution, assuming defaults - this may fail." >&2
  else
    echo "Init system discovered: $SYSTEMINITDAEMON"
  fi
}
```

Comment: I think the use of `/proc` ties this down to Linux (if suitably configured) and one or two others - it's certainly far from universal.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of compatibility pitfalls when testing systemd vs initd. This actually works on OpenSuSE 42.1: `ps --pid 1 | grep -q systemd && echo 'systemd' || echo 'init'`

Answer (score 1):

My solution: check the command running as process with ID 1.

```
case `cat /proc/1/comm` in
    init)    echo Init ;;
    systemd) echo SystemD ;;
    # add here other patterns
    *)       echo "unknown: '`cat /proc/1/comm`'" ;;
esac
```

At the moment I have access only to Init and SystemD machines, so I can't Tell how Upstart or macOS (OS X) will be detected, but I'll keep searching.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `pstree` and simply find its root. On my `Ubuntu`, `Arch` and `Fedora` systems (unfortunately all use `systemd` for `init`), running `pstree` gives me the following output head:

```
systemd-+-GUIPool-+-calibre-paralle
        |         `-8*[{GUIPool}]
        |-MainThread-+-Privileged Cont---29*[{Privileged Cont}]
        |            |-Web Content---30*[{Web Content}]
        |            |-Web Content---32*[{Web Content}]
```

1. So, as a simple solution using `pstree`, `head` and `cut` which are come preinstalled on most systems, I'd run `pstree | head -n 1 | cut -d "-" -f 1,1`
   It threw the needed string "systemd" at me on all three OSs I tested it on.
2. Alternately, you could run something like
   `pstree | head -n 1 | ([[ $(grep systemd) ]] && echo systemd) || ([[ $(grep upstart) ]] && echo upstart) || ([[ $(grep sysvinit) ]] && echo sysvinit)`

Answer (score 0):

```
check(){
    if hash systemctl 2>/dev/null;
    then
        echo "there is systemd"
    fi

    if hash initctl 2>/dev/null;
    then
        echo "there is upStart"
    fi

    if [ -f "/etc/inittab"];
    then
        echo "there is systemV"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How'bout this one :

```
strings $(\ps -p 1 o cmd= | cut -d" " -f1) | egrep -o "upstart|sysvinit|systemd" | head -1
```

Only tested on the systems I have: Ubuntu and SailfishOS.

Answer (score 0):

### My ultimate solution.

As [*`upstart`*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart_(software)) seem dead and I don't them anywhere, I'm not able to test what's happen if I hit `ps -C upstart` on *`upstart`* based host.

Trying different `ps 1` was definitively not efficient in all my tested hosts...

My purpose is finally:

```
if ps -C systemd | grep -q '^ *1 ' ;then
    echo This system run systemd
else
    echo This system run init
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

### Check to see if my system *has `systemd` available*

For anyone wondering if your system *has* `systemd`, not if it *was booted* by `systemd`, these are the easiest commands I could come up with. I'm using this to test if my custom embedded Linux board successfully got `systemd` onto it from [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/):

```bash
# best: check the systemd-run version
systemd-run --version

# or: look for any "systemd" files or folders on your computer
find / | grep -i systemd | sort -V

# or: look for "systemd" files in /usr/bin
find /usr/bin | grep -i systemd | sort -V
```

For my board, I get the following output:

**1st command:**

```bash
# systemd-run --version
systemd 244 (244)
-PAM -AUDIT -SELINUX -IMA -APPARMOR -SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP -LIBCRYPTSETUP -GCRYPT -GNUTLS -ACL -XZ -LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 -IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

My [`systemd.mk` makefile in Buildroot](https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/master/package/systemd/systemd.mk#L22) shows `SYSTEMD_VERSION = 244.3`, so this makes sense.

**2nd command:**

It's too long for me to care to copy/paste it all, but it shows entries in `/usr/lib/systemd`, `/usr/bin/systemd*`, etc.

**3rd command:**

```bash
# find /usr/bin | grep -i systemd | sort -V
/usr/bin/systemd-analyze
/usr/bin/systemd-ask-password
/usr/bin/systemd-cat
/usr/bin/systemd-cgls
/usr/bin/systemd-cgtop
/usr/bin/systemd-delta
/usr/bin/systemd-detect-virt
/usr/bin/systemd-escape
/usr/bin/systemd-id128
/usr/bin/systemd-machine-id-setup
/usr/bin/systemd-mount
/usr/bin/systemd-notify
/usr/bin/systemd-nspawn
/usr/bin/systemd-path
/usr/bin/systemd-run
/usr/bin/systemd-socket-activate
/usr/bin/systemd-stdio-bridge
/usr/bin/systemd-tty-ask-password-agent
/usr/bin/systemd-umount
```

This is the list from which I found the `systemd-run` executable. I simply guessed that running `systemd-run --version` might work, and sure enough, it did!

### See also

1. [Super User: How to know if I am using systemd on Linux?](https://superuser.com/q/1017959/425838)
2. [Convenient way to check if system is using systemd or sysvinit in BASH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121654/114401)