# How to determine which init system is used?

Tags: linux, systemd, init, upstart, sysvinit

Is there a way to determine which init system is being used in Linux? (such as sysvinit, upstart, systemd, etc.) I don't care if it can be programmatically determined, I just want to know how I can figure it out.

I'm aware of [Bash- detect init system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18209/bash-detect-init-system), but that is about detecting the init system from bash in order to write a cross-init-system daemon. The answers from it do not provide a clear way to determine this because they are targeting specifically a programmatic solution which I am not interested in.