# should I disable both systemd and sysvinit to disable a service from run level?

Tags: linux, systemd

My application should run on systems which run on systemd and older platforms where systemd is not available. So I am registering my service into run level using both chkconfig and systemctl enable.

What should I do to disable my service from run level? Should I disable using both systemctl and chkconfig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clean solution is to [check which init system is in use](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18209/detect-init-system-using-the-shell) and then only run the command which applies to the init system that's in use.

Answer (score 0):

For `sysvinit` systems `chkconfig` create a link to the script that run your service from `/etc/rc.d/init.d` and put it on `/etc/rc*.d` depending on the run level you specify for your service.

For `systemd` systems `systemctl enable` create a link and put it in different folder from the `chkconfig` in the `sysvinit` systems.

For example, for multi user level its put it in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/`

For you situation if you have a running script in `/etc/init.d`
So when you call `systemd disable` it remove the link from `/etc/systemd/system/X/`
But when you call `chkconfig` in `sysvinit` it remove the link from `/etc/rc*.d`

Comment: But just disabling using systemctl works for me. I do have the script inside `/etc/init.d/`

Comment: `[nithinj@vbox ~]$ chkconfig --list $servicename

Note: This output shows SysV services only and does not include native
      systemd services. SysV configuration data might be overridden by native systemd configuration.`. I assume the chkconfig data got overridden while disabling using systemctl. Thanks.

Comment: @NithinJ you are right, i removed the last line in my answer

Comment: Your answer is very much detailed. It will be helpful to add a one line answer (brief) in the top. Thanks.