# Flavour of initrd

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, manjaro, initrd

[This Arch wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Specialties#Discard.2FTRIM_support_for_solid_state_drives_.28SSD.29) says:

> If you are using a systemd based initrd, you must pass:
>    `rd.luks.options=discard`

How do I query the `initrd` mini-shell to find out if I am running a `systemd`-based `initrd`?

What are the other possible types of `initrd`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect init system using the shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18209/detect-init-system-using-the-shell)

Comment: @MarkStosberg No, the initrd/initramfs is a rather different context. The other question applies to a system that has already booted.

Comment: If you used the `systemd` hook when creating your `initramfs` with `mkinitcpio` that will install a basic `systemd` setup in your `initramfs` - that is a `systemd`-based `initramfs` (or `initrd`). As to how you determine that from the minimalist shell - I have no arch setup here  right now, I guess if the `systemctl` binary is present then you're on a `systemd`-based `initrd`