# How do I correctly check, if the system uses systemd?

Tags: systemd

On my debian 10 server `pidof systemd` gives no result, although there are pids:

```
# pgrep systemd -la
1 /sbin/init
256 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
275 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
282 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
355 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
```

I would like to check in a general bash-install-script, if the current system uses systemd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documented way](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_booted.html) to check that systemd is managing the running system is to check for the existence of the `/run/systemd/system` directory. If it exists, systemd booted the system.

See also [Detect init system using the shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18209/86440).