# Check whether linux is utilizing service or systemctl with a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, debian, ubuntu, apt

friends!

I need a mechanism to verify if the linux virtual private server is utilizing systemctl or service.

The `systemd` application is installed on all of them.

#### Current Code.

```
if pgrep systemd-journal; then
    systemctl restart unbound
else
    service unbound restart
fi
```

Comment: what's 'service'?

Comment: updated the description.

Comment: Just need a stable way to check either the system is using service or systemctl.

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18209/117549?

Comment: `service` works anyways here on systemd'ed Fedora 35. file `which service`
/usr/sbin/service: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable

Comment: *Why* do you need to know? When `systemctl` is available, all services can be controlled with it. It does not make sense to use an older compatibility mechanism when establishing new services.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps --no-headers -o comm 1
```

This returns either systemd or init and appears reliable across Linux distributions and releases.