# How to disable autologin in UART console

Tags: autologin

We use card with embedded Linux: 4.1.22-ltsi , "Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)".

On Uart console, after boot process, it automatically does login and shows prompt

```
root@linaro-developer:
root@linaro-developer: who am i
root ttyS0 2016-11-03 17:16
```

Problem:

How to change Linux configuration to disable such auto login
to allow secure connection to the card?

Please see below /etc/inittab file

```
# /etc/inittab
#
# Copyright (C) 2001 Erik Andersen <andersen@codepoet.org>
#
# Note: BusyBox init doesn't support runlevels.  The runlevels field is
# completely ignored by BusyBox init. If you want runlevels, use
# sysvinit.
#
# Format for each entry: <id>:<runlevels>:<action>:<process>
#
# id        == tty to run on, or empty for /dev/console
# runlevels == ignored
# action    == one of sysinit, respawn, askfirst, wait, and once
# process   == program to run

# Startup the system
null::sysinit:/bin/mount -t proc proc /proc
null::sysinit:/bin/mount -o remount,rw /
null::sysinit:/bin/mkdir -p /dev/pts
null::sysinit:/bin/mkdir -p /dev/shm
null::sysinit:/bin/mount -a
null::sysinit:/bin/hostname -F /etc/hostname
# now run any rc scripts
::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS

# Do not ask for a password at boot
console::respawn:-/bin/sh
# Put a getty on the serial port
# console::respawn:/sbin/getty -L  console 115200 vt100 # GENERIC_SERIAL

# Stuff to do for the 3-finger salute
::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/reboot

# Stuff to do before rebooting
::shutdown:/etc/init.d/rcK
::shutdown:/sbin/swapoff -a
::shutdown:/bin/umount -a -r
```

**Edited after @MC68020 post.**

According to @MC68020 recommendation I did changes as below, **but no result!**

Instead of

```
# Do not ask for a password at boot
console::respawn:-/bin/sh
# Put a getty on the serial port
# console::respawn:/sbin/getty -L  console 115200 vt100 # GENERIC_SERIAL
```

I set

```
# Do not ask for a password at boot
# console::respawn:-/bin/sh
# Put a getty on the serial port
console::respawn:/sbin/getty -L  console 115200 vt100
```

Comment: What do you mean by »embedded card«? Please share your kernel parameters.

Comment: »embedded card« - I edit my post (by the way, thanks for good edit). Regarding of "kernel parameters" - what you mean? I not so good in Kernel, please give me a command to run.

Comment: BTW which init system are your running ? openrc ? systemd ? busybox ? I had assumed openrc but wrongly as it apprears.

Comment: I'm not so Linux specialist. Based on [Detect Init](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18209/detect-init-system-using-the-shell) I run **lsof -a -p 1 -d txt** that output is **/lib/systemd/systemd**.

Answer (score 2):

The [/etc/inittab](https://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/man/inittab-man-page.php) file describes which and how processes are started at bootup and during normal operation.
The process launched by *init* in order to manage terminals is [getty](http://www.skrenta.com/rt/man/getty.1.html) which, in turn, will launch the /bin/login process according to the parameters given to the command.

Have a look into your /etc/inittab, you will probably read something like :

```
s0:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -a root -L 115200 ttyS0 vt100
```

Notice the **-a** option which enables the autologin you do not wish on your **ttyS0**.
So just remove it (together with the following user name.)

---

**Edit after more info regarding OP's inittab :**

You understand that the line `console::respawn:-/bin/sh` instructs init to bypass getty and directly fork the shell on the console. So… simply remove it or comment it out.
And instead remove the comment sign leading the one that should launch getty and incidentally the login process : `console::respawn:/sbin/getty -L  console 115200 vt100 # GENERIC_SERIAL`

---

And BTW, d'better be safe than sorry… ensure that you get valid username / password associations prior to making the change…

Comment: Thank you for the help, I added  /etc/inittab file in may main post, please see it

Comment: @Yakov : I edited my answer according to your info.

Comment: I changed the **inittab** file as @MC68020 recommendation, but the problem still exists. Please see my post update.