# Is there a way to make tail -F beep?

Tags: less, tail, bell

Is there a way to make `tail -F` or `less` beep (ring the bell in a terminal) when new data comes in (a new line is added to the file).
Or is there any other unix utility to do this on a linux or mac.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An idea migth be to pipe the output of `tail` through `sed` and replace the newline with bell/newline.

But there is propably an easier solution if you use `tail` within an **x-window**. There your can execute an action when the content of the window changes (flicker, bell, whatever).

Comment: Don't replace the newline, add it at the end of the line.

Comment: @Nils, this `sed` Idea is brilliant but I don't know enough 'sed' to make it work, it looks like I cant capture newlines in the regexpt the usual way (that I am used to), I guess I need to tell sed dont interpret the incoming stream line by line.

Comment: @Ali Indeed, sed acts line by line and you don't directly see the newlines. `sed -e $'s/$/\a/'` adds a `$'\a'` (bell character in ksh/bash/zsh syntax) at the end of each line.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles , worked like a charm (on a mac too)! `sed` regexpt is a bit odd to my naive eyes.

Comment: @Gilles: Note that the `$'...'` syntax is not universal.  For example, [t]csh doesn't support it.

Comment: @KeithThompson: That's not the only kind of quoting that [t]csh doesn't support!

Answer (score 13):

if you use GNU `screen`, you can set it to "watch" the window with the tail, and it will alert you in your status bar, or by your termcap's defined bell, that there is new output in that window.

http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html%5Fnode/Monitor.html#Monitor

---

**edit: just had to add this, since you mentioned mac os x**

just for fun, if you were looking for something in particular, you can use Mac OS X's `say` command to read you the file you're watching.  just get the `logtail` command, from:

http://www.hmug.org/pub/MacOS_X/BSD/Administration/Log/logcheck/

And use it in a script like:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
offset=$(basename "$1")

# while true... let this thing run until it's killed...
while true; do
    output=$(/usr/local/bin/logtail $file .${offset}.offset)
    if [ ! -z "$output" ]; then

        # print the output and say ding
        echo "$output" && say ding
        # to have the file read aloud to you, uncomment the following:
        say "$output"

        fi
    # recheck every 5 seconds
    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim, `screen` , shows and alert (I guess I can make it ring the bell as well) ONLY ONCE. Not for every new event that happens (not for every new line that is available)

Comment: i added an example for mac that could read the file to you.  you could change that to work for linux by installing the linux version of logtail, and using the `beep` command, instead of `say`.

Comment: cool! That is creative, although in my case I am using the beep to be able to monitor a log file without looking at screen. And the actual beep may be better than a voice.

Comment: Can also use screen's `exec` command to do it as well.  The example in the manpage is `!:sed -n s/.*Error.*/\007/p` which will send a bell each time "Error" is displayed in that window.

Comment: Same applies to Tmux.

Answer (score 10):

You could use [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/examples.html). It is an *enhanced* tail that supports command execution on regular expression match.

E.g. the following command plays a sound and opens an xmessage window each time a *martian source* packet is logged.

```
multitail -ex "martian source" "play beep.wav; xmessage " -i /var/log/messages
```

Answer (score 6):

Just for the record, as @Nils suggested I am using `sed` to add a `bell` to each line.

The `sed` line provided by @Gilles

```
sed -e $'s/$/\a/'
```

works on my mac (I enabled "audible bell" and "visual bell" in my Terminal\preferences\advanced).

Comment: Of note is that `$'...'` escape sequences are a Bash-only thing.

Comment: @amphetamachine thanks, while I am a bash user myself, it would be nice if you or others can add versions that would work on other shells as well.

Comment: I'm also a bash user, but [I'm slowly learning](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24146/avoiding-bash-isms-in-shell-scripts) what will and won't work in other shells.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who finds this page, I'm using tcsh and this seems to work:

```
tail -f changingfile | sed -e 's/.*/& \a/'
```

Don't ask me what the sed syntax means...

Comment: I can't help myself, I've to ask, can you explain sed expression?

Answer (score -1):

You can try `konsole` which allows alert on new activity (or silence) in any given tab.

Comment: I imagine `konsole` would be like `screen` it alerts once, while I need to receive an alert for every new line.