# Is there a way to beep when tail -F stops to fetch new results?

Tags: shell, logs, monitoring, tail, bell

A few days ago I asked [Is there a way to make tail -F beep?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25211/is-there-a-way-to-make-tail-f-beep)

Now I want to know if there is any way to use *nix utilities, to beep when a `tail -F` stops returning new lines for a while!

I know, I can write a simple application in any language to do this, but I was curious to know if there is a way to do this just by standard (or semi standard) utils.

The goals is to beep when a file (like a log file) no longer grows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tail -F asdf.log | while true; do if read -t 1 LINE; then echo $LINE; else echo beep; fi; done
```

(Change the number after `-t` to the number of seconds of inactivity you want)

Comment: @cupgeniusmv cool! What in heavens name is `read` and why it doesn't have its own man page. Still `read -t` is very cool, I didn't know there is such a thing.

Comment: By the way I imagine I can pass `$LINE` to `awk` or `sod` if I am interested in further manipulations, but just out of curiosity that would be nice to see if there are other solutions maybe involving `awk` or `sed` without a `while` and `read -t` !

Comment: `read` is a bash builtin function. It's also one of the worst words to search for in the bash man page! :) In the version I have here, it's around line 3350.

Comment: You can ask `type read` to see what it is. As it is a shell builtin, you can ask `help read` for usage information.

Comment: On mac osx 10.7 it's on lines 2978-3006.

Comment: `info bash`, then `s` for search, then type "`read'" (backtick, "read", apostrophe).  Command names, keywords, and so forth are delimited by a backtick and an apostrophe, which makes them relatively easy to search for.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `silence` monitor in `screen(1)`.  You can set it for a certain period of 'silence' (no input/output) and a visual or audible bell will be sounded.

Comment: thanks, for my use, it has too problems, 1- it needs for the affected "window" to be sent to background (which I don't want) 2- My screen, does not ring the bell it just displays a line in the  message line.

Comment: For 2, use the `vbell` command to toggle between visual and audible bell.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a log file called *log.txt*. If *log.txt* is not updated for at least *5* seconds, this command will warn the user by a beep sound:

```
perl -e 'for(;;){$p=$z;$z=`wc -l log.txt`;if ($z==$p) {print "\a";}sleep(5);}'
```

It's ugly but it works ;)

Comment: It is really ugly! But still it works fine, on every descent OS. How did you get to learn this?!