# How to use Bash for sh in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, ubuntu, rpm

I am installing a huge program, which has its resources as an `rpm` file. It stuck at the line of

```
#!/bin/sh
SCITEGICPERLBIN=`dirname $0`
SCITEGICPERLHOME=`dirname $SCITEGICPERLBIN`
if [ $SCITEGICPERLHOME == "." ]
```

Apparently, `sh` work for `bash` in Red Hat Linux with this syntax, but it gives the error of `unexpected operator` in Ubuntu.

I cannot change the script to `bash` as the script comes from the `rpm` package. I can extract and repack the `rpm` package, but there might be many of such scripts.

Is there a way to change the shell default to treat `#!/bin/sh` as `bash` or anything else, which can handle the `[` operator?

Comment: The only thing wrong is the `==` that should be `=`. That, and that the variable expansions should be double quoted.

Comment: `[` is not an operator, but a builtin command that is called `test`. The unexpected operator is `==` and this should be replaced by `=` because it is not POSIX compliant.

Comment: The second only thing that is wrong is that `$SCITEGICPERLHOME` should be quoted.

Comment: You should complain to the author of the program. If they use `#!/bin/sh`, they should make sure they only use POSIX shell features, not `bash` extensions. This programmer is very sloppy. He should either fix his code or use `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: For people wondering about other similar issues here is a list of "[Bashisms](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism)". Also see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24146/121116).

Comment: Huh, do some distributions still use bash as sh by default?!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There are multiple programs that implement the language of `/bin/sh`. On Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is dash, which is designed to be fast, to use a small amount of memory, and doesn't support much more than the minimum expected from `/bin/sh`. On RHEL, `/bin/sh` is bash, which is slower and uses more memory but has more features. One of these features is the `==` operator for the `[` conditional syntax. Dash supports `[`, which is a basic sh feature, but it doesn't have the `==` operator which is a bash (and ksh and zsh) extension.

You can switch your system to using bash. On Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `dash`. You can make it a symbolic link to `bash` instead. Current versions of Debian and Ubuntu (and derivatives) make this an installation option of dash. To change it, run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

and answer “yes” to keep dash as `/bin/sh` or “no” to switch to bash.

You can keep bash as `/bin/sh`, but it'll make your system a bit slower. It's even conceivable that some system script is incompatible with bash, although that's unlikely since bash is mostly a superset of dash.

---

For distributions which don't have an interface to choose between implementations of `/bin/sh`, here's how to switch to bash.

```
sudo ln -s bash /bin/sh.bash
sudo mv /bin/sh.bash /bin/sh
```

Keep a terminal open and check that you can still run some `sh` scripts after that. If you mess up this command, it'll make your system unusable. (By the way, the reason I used the multiple commands above rather than the straightforward-looking `sudo ln -sf bash /bin/sh` is that `ln -sf` is not atomic. In the admittedly unlikely case your computer crashed during this operation, you'd need to boot from rescue media to restore it. In contrast, `mv` is atomic.)

To restore dash as `/bin/sh`:

```
sudo ln -s dash /bin/sh.dash
sudo mv /bin/sh.dash /bin/sh
```

Note that if sh is `/bin/bash` by default on your distribution, switching to dash may cause scripts to fail, because bash has many more features than dash. Bash scripts should start with `#!/bin/bash`, and scripts starting with `#!/bin/sh` should not use bash-specific features, but distributions that ship with bash as `/bin/sh` may use bash-specific features in `#!/bin/sh` scripts that are specific to that distribution (it's ok as long as there's no expectation that users can switch to dash as `/bin/sh` and there's no expectations that these scripts work on another distribution).

Comment: In my not so humble opinion, if some script fails when `/bin/sh` is Bash, it's a bug either in the system (the package with the script), or in Bash's `sh`-mode. Like Stephen says, the system explicitly allows for setting `/bin/sh` back to Bash, via `dpkg-reconfigure`. It's also mentioned as a possibility in the Ubuntu wiki on this matter: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, if a script fails if `/bin/sh` is bash, it's a bug. However, bugs happen. I recommend sticking to the default if you're not capable and willing to diagnose such bugs because other people have tested it for you. I used dash as `/bin/sh` before it was officially supported on Debian, but this was a risk I took, knowing that I'd be able to cope if something happened.

Comment: Note that manually overridden symlinks will be restored to whatever configuration is stored in `debconf` the next time `dash` is updated; admittedly this won’t happen often (if at all, in a given release) for systems running Debian stable.

Answer (score 53):

Up to Ubuntu 22.04 included (and Debian 11 included), you can switch `sh` to `bash` (instead of `dash`, the default) by reconfiguring `dash` (yes, it’s somewhat counter-intuitive):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

This will ask whether you want `dash` to be the default system shell; answer “No” (<kbd>Tab</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and `bash` will become the default instead (*i.e.* `/bin/sh` will point to `/bin/bash`).

Since Ubuntu 22.10 and Debian 12, this is no longer supported; if you want to switch `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`, you’ll have to symlink it manually. See [Gilles’ answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442518/86440) for details.

Comment: Your solution is indeed the most reasonable one, but I accepted another answer because of detailed descriptions clarifying the issue. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Debian bookworm has removed this method: "From DebianSqueeze to DebianBullseye, it was possible to select bash as the target of the /bin/sh symlink (by running dpkg-reconfigure dash). As of DebianBookworm, this is no longer supported." See https://wiki.debian.org/Shell. Would expect Ubuntu to follow soon.