# How does `execve()` call a special start-up routine and the main() function?

Tags: linux, system-calls, exec

When a C program is executed by the kernel—by `execve()`,

- where does `execve()` call a  special  start-up  routine `crt0` which is  called  before the main function  is  called?
- where does `execve()` call the main function?

I can't find them out in https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/exec.c.

From Understanding the Linux Kernel, `execve()` internally looks for a `linux_binfmt` object whose `load_binary()` can load the executable file and call its `load_binary()` method to load it, and also load the dynamic linker to load and link the shared libraries used by the executable file.  But the book doesn't say how `execve()` then calls the startup routine `crt0` and then `main()` of the program from the executable file.

Thanks.

Comment: Poor little `execve()` has no idea what you are speaking about. That a C language program begins execution (as far as the programmer is concerned) with a call to `main()` is a feature of the C language. Other languages have other conventions. It's the job of the linker to arrange it so that the startup code for the C language runtime calls `main()`. All `execve()` does is load the image and start running the process at the *actual* entry point of the executable, as specified by the linker which created the executable image.

Comment: Where does execve() "start running the process at the actual entry point of the executable"?

Comment: `retval = exec_binprm(bprm);` (line 1819).

Comment: Inside `execve()`, `exec_binprm` is a very high level function, which loads the executable file and dynamic linker among other things. That doesn't answer my question of how execve() then calls the startup routine crt0 and then main() of the program from the executable file.

Comment: *It does not call the crt0*. It start executing the process at the entry point which the linker set in the executable image. It *does not have* the slightest idea about crt0.

Comment: What is "the entry point which the linker set in the executable image"?

Comment: [Executable and Linkable Format (ELF)](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf); element `e_entry` in the ELF header.

Comment: Does `e_entry` store the address of `main()` of the executable, or the startup routine `crt0`?

Comment: The [link editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) sets `e_entry` to the address of the first machine instruction to be executed. Where this machine instruction comes from depends on the programming language and runtime library. For programs written in a higher-level language, it is an entry point in the runtime library which is responsible for setting things up and calling the main program according to the conventions of that language. I confess that I have never been curious to find out what's the name of the library routine which calls `main()` for C language programs.

Comment: @AlexP quite surprisingly, in glibc it's called `__libc_start_main()`. You can override it from a preloaded library and [exec another binary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468289/separate-environment-with-different-bin-sh/468501#468501) instead. But that's not the entry point -- it's itself called from the `_start` function, which is the default entry point.

Comment: I suggest you learn more things about dynamic and static linking.

Answer (score 5):

Neither `execve` nor the kernel code do call the `_start` function (the entry point of an executable, whatever it's called), ever.

That's because they're running in different *contexts*; think as if they were running on different machines.

What happens is that the kernel arranges for the `execve` system call, upon returning to user mode, to have the `IP` (instruction pointer) register set to point to the beginning of the `_start` function, and the `SP` (stack pointer) register set to point to the beginning of the argv + env string list, so the effect from the point of view of user mode is as if *someone* had called the `_start` function as:

```
_start(argc, argv0, argv1, ... , NULL, env0, env1, ... NULL)
```

in a calling convention where all arguments are passed  on the stack.

Of course, before that, the kernel had taken care of copying those argv + env at the right place, mapping the segment containing the `_start` function, etc.

---

Notice that the argv + env strings are all packed together in a single chunk, eg.

```
"prog\0arg1\0arg2\0VAR1=foo\0VAR2=bar\0"
```

The virtual addresses where that chunk begins and ends are accessible via the `/proc/PID/stat` file; quoting from the `procfs(5)` manpage:

> ```
> (48) arg_start  %lu  (since Linux 3.5)  [PT]
>         Address  above  which  program  command-line arguments
>         (argv) are placed.
>
> (49) arg_end  %lu  (since Linux 3.5)  [PT]
>         Address below program  command-line  arguments  (argv)
>         are placed.
> ```

Writing to that address will modify whatever appears in the `ps` output:

```
$ sleep 3600 3600 3600 3600 3600 3600 3600 &
[2] 4927
$ awk '{print $48,$49,$49-$48-1}' /proc/4927/stat
140735402952841 140735402952882 40
$ printf 'Somebody set up us the bomb Main screen turn on\0' | dd bs=1 count=40 of
=/proc/4927/mem seek=140735402952841 conv=notrunc
40+0 records in
40+0 records out
40 bytes copied, 0.000229779 s, 174 kB/s
$ ps 4927
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 4927 pts/4    S      0:00 Somebody set up us the bomb Main screen
```

Comment: Thanks. (1) "the kernel had taked care of copying those argv + env at the right place, mapping the segment containing the _start function, etc." Do you mean `execve()` has to take care of that? (2) What is "the entry point of an executable"? Is it `main()` of the executable or the startup routine `crt0`?

Comment: 1. No, execve is a system call. The execve func from glibc is simply a wrapper. 2. the entry point doesn't have to be named in any particular way. `_start` is its *usual* name. All it has to do is to be pointed to from the ELF header. In any case it could not be main(), because its arguments are passed in a different manner, as you could've gathered if you did read my answer.

Comment: FWIW I don't think that the startup func was ever called `crt0`. That's usually the name of the object file that contains the `_start` func, and which should be linked in when building static executables.

Comment: Wouldn't the kernel point `RIP`(instruction pointer) to the final loader ELF's entry point? In case of a process execve a ELF-with-PT_INTERP or script-with-shebang or trigger some `binfmt_misc` rule? Especially when the specified userspace loader are recursively defined.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 in the case of an ELF with interpreter it's the interpreter which is actually executed and the execve will return pointing to its _start function -- which could do then as it pleases (eg not run any code from the original file at all).

Comment: Understanding the Linux Kernel says `execve()` calls `load_binary()` of each `linux_binfmt` object, and `load_binary()`  " Invokes the start_thread( ) macro to modify the values of the User Mode registers eip and esp saved on the Kernel Mode stack, so that they point to the entry point of the dynamic linker and to the top of the new User Mode stack, respectively".

Comment: You wrote "What happens is that the kernel arranges for the execve system call, upon returning to user mode, to have the IP (instruction pointer) register set to point to the beginning of the _start function, and the SP (stack pointer) register set to point to the beginning of the argv + env string list". Which one is correct?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498430/does-execve-set-up-registers-to-invoke-dynamic-linker-or-the-executable-to-b

Comment: @Tim I don't care what that book says. I believe that my description is accurate, with the addition that when the ELF binary has a pt_interp in the header, it's the interpreter which is executed instead, ie the IP will be pointed to the interpreter's entry point (and the entry point of the original binary will be saved in the AUX vector); but I'm not going to add that to the answer, because it's only cluttering the point.

Comment: Thanks. How does `execve()` invoke the dynamic linker to load and link the shared libraries then?

Comment: `execve()` doesn't deal with shared libraries. It simply mmap the interpreter and original  ELF then point IP to interpreter (or recursively).