# Do all c programs need to load a library?

Tags: linux, c, libraries

With a program like

```
int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

- and you statically link, will some library on your system be linked into the final binary.
- and you dynamically link, will a library be loaded when it's run?

In essence, is a library always required for even the simplest programs, if so why? I ask because I thought the canonical entry point for anything that wants to be executed is actually _start (which I thought was in a library, namely glibc). Maybe I don't understand what _start really does with regard to setting things up, so any pointers there would be helpful too.

Comment: Existence proof: the Linux kernel is a C program that does not load a library.

Comment: Note that a static library is in principle just a collection of object files. Instead of linking with a library (and leaving it to the linker to extract the functions you need from the library) you can simply link against the object files directly. Since object files are simply compiled or assembled source files you can also simply first compile (or assemble) the files yourself if you have the sources. You don't need *any* binaries. (I'm not perfectly sure whether that's different with the runtime lib because interacts low-level with the operating system -- I'm curious to hear comments).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to write your program in standard portable C, you need of course some runtime that calls the `main()` function in the first place.

But if you don't care about that, you can dispense with any library, and do system calls directly via inline assembly. Eg. for x86-64:

```
$ cat q.c
#include <sys/syscall.h>
void _start(void){
        __asm__( "syscall" : : "D"(0), "a"(SYS_exit) );
}
$ cc -O2 -static -nostdlib -nostartfiles -Wall q.c -o q
$ strace ./q
execve("./q", ["./q"], 0x7fffc72d8d20 /* 39 vars */) = 0
exit(0)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

You have to do at least one system call, namely `_exit(2)`, unless exit-by-crashing is acceptable for a "simplest program", in which case an empty file will do, too ;-):

```
$ > foo.c
$ cc -static -nostdlib -nostartfiles -Wall foo.c -o ./foo
/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000401000
$ ./foo
Segmentation fault
```

> I thought the canonical entry point for anything that wants to be executed is actually `_start`

there's nothing canonical about it; `_start` is the default name the linker will use; you can point it elsewhere with the `-e sym` option (`-Wl,-e,sym` with `gcc`).

Comment: That's very useful information, I want to give the correct answer, but could you clarify on my question a little: I'm guessing from your answer there's a runtime.so or .a or something like that which gets linked and/or loaded.

Comment: Yes, it is. At least the `crt*.o` objects will have to be linked in, because they contain the code which ultimately calls `main` (via a `__libc_start_main()` wrapper on Linux)

Comment: Awesome clear answer. The in line assembly and -nostdlib -nostartfiles were really nice examples to help understand too.

Comment: I think this link can be entertaining: [A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html)

Comment: @mosvy Why are the crt*.o files object files and not .a or .so files. I thought, as they typically come from libc, that they would be compiled into that format as other lib files seem to be.

Comment: The `*.a` files are archives which contain `*.o` files. You can see their content with the `ar tf`.They could've put those too in an archive, but they just didn't. As to the `*.so` files, they're completely different, they're for dynamically linked executables: no part of their content is stored in the executable, but only a reference to them, so that the dynamic linker (elf interpreter) can load them at run time.

Comment: @AndrewCina you can also read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/498524/308316) about why that crt* code is necessary instead of the kernel just using `main` as the entry point, even for statically linked executables (basically: unpacking of the argc + argv and calling static constructors + destructors for c++ code)

Comment: I think trying to link the OP's main.o into an executable with `-nostdlib` or equivalent will reveal which symbols would be linked from e.g. glibc.

Comment: @Peter no symbols will be linked in that case; the linker will set the entry point to some default value, and the "program" will work just like my 2nd example. But if you compile it with `-nodefaultlibs` (which will link in the `crt*.o` ini + fini files from libc but not the rest of the library) you will see that the `crt*.o` code calls through the `__libc_start_main` and `__libc_csu_init` hooks, but you can override those yourself, via either statically or [dynamically](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/468501/308316) linked code.

Comment: @Peter that is a feature of glibc, also available in musl and uclibc (the latter with a different name `__uClibc_main`, if they haven't changed it recently). On other systems, the `_start` glue code will call directly into `main()`.

Comment: @mosvy I found that you can actually have an entry-point at main and have it execute successfully so long as a call to exit is made.

Comment: @AndrewCina that's exactly what I've told you: the name doesn't matter. You can set the entry to whatever you like, eg change `_start` to `main` and compile it with `-Wl,-e,main`.

Comment: @mosvy, yes you did. I confused myself regarding "portable c" in your first comment. Does having to use `-e` if `main` should be your entry point make it not "portable"? Also, if crt*.o files are merely object files, even though they are generated from libc, can't you argue they are not library files? Finally, if crt*.o is linked against your program, it must always be statically linked, no? And would the answer to my original question, specifically regarding dynamically linking, mean that no other libraries are actually loaded in that example?

Comment: @AndrewCina yes. just assuming anything about how `main` is called and how its return value is  handled is completely unportable. Even the modern Unices are very different (eg. the `__libc_start_main` trick doesn't work on *BSD or Solaris).

Comment: `*.o` files can only be linked statically. Compiling a simple standard C example like `int main(){}` on Linux will statically link in the `crt*.o` files, and either link dynamically to the standard C library (`libc.so.*`) or pull in quite a lot of stuff from it (just compile it with `cc -static -xc - <<<'int main(){}' -o a.out` and analyze the executable with `objdump -xd a.out`). FWIW, even a dynamically linked executable will statically link in stuff from the `elf-init.o` file from `libc.a`.