# Is there a free implementation of /bin/sh with no extensions?

Tags: shell-script, shell

I would like to develop portable `/bin/sh` scripts, but my environment links `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`. Even when running in `--posix` mode, `/bin/bash` still handles some non-portable features like `[[` and `$()`. I am (now) aware that these are <strike>`bash` extensions</strike> not portable, but I don't know what other syntax I'm using that isn't always available.

Is there a free implementation of `/bin/sh` which rejects non-portable constructs that I could use to test whether my scripts don't use any `bash`-isms?

Comment: `$()` is not a bashism.  `dash` might be a good option, but also has at least a few non-sh caveats.

Comment: I was under the impression that backticks `` were the only `/bin/sh`-compatible way to do what you can do with `$()` in bash. Is `$()` part of POSIX then?

Comment: Yes. `$(...)` [is POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) and [should be preferred over backticks](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Comment: But only a few shell implementations (e.g. new ksh93 and bosh) implement $(...) correctly. See: https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/cmd-subst/ This is because it is not easy to parse $(...) correctly as you need a recursive parser.

Comment: This question relies upon the erroneous premise that using a particular shell is the only way to check for non-portable shell constructs.  _How can I check scripts for non-portable shell constructs?  What tools can help me?_ is a question that would have garnered more comprehensive pointers towards the actual goal.  But we've already had questions like that for years now, at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9997/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24146/ , and the like.

Comment: Using a shell that rejects non-portable constructs would be the *easiest* way to discover bugs. A linter would be only slightly less convenient. A list of documented rules is extremely error-prone. But I admit my question definitely conflates `/bin/sh` with POSIX. As an example, according to [lintsh](http://code.dogmap.org/lintsh/) (which asking this question helped me to find), `$()` is not portable despite being POSIX because Solaris outright refuses to recognize it, in addition to the potential issues @schily alluded to.

Comment: Since any even small feature in `bosh` may be configured at compile time (check `Makefile`), you could e.g. create a shell variant that does not permit enhancements.

Answer (score 2):

How about `bosh` the POSIXified Bourne Shell:

It still has some extensions but they are well documented:

http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html

It is faster than `dash` and a bit slower than `ksh93` which makes it the second fastest shell.

Note that `dash` does not support multi byte characters and thus is only useful for small embedded systems.

BTW: `bosh` allows to fine grained configure the behavior. The Solaris-10 compatible `osh` is compiled from the same source as `bosh`. Have a look at `Makefile`. When I have some time, I may have a look whether I could create a preconfigured `Makefile` for that purpose.

Update:
During the past days, I created a new compile variant of "bosh" and call it "pbosh". It will be included in the next scheduled schilytools snapshot that will most likely be published on June 29 or July 2 2018.

"pbosh" is a shell that is intended to test shell scripts for portability.

It does not implement extensions on POSIX and thus would fail, in case
that a shell feature beyond the POSIX standard is used.

Please keep in mind that a script that works with "pbosh" still may fail
with other shells as POSIX has some features unspecified. One example is
the way how pipelines are created. "pbosh" implements the optimized method
and moreover runs the rightmost program from a pipe inside the shell
process in case that this is a shell builtin. As a result, it is most likely
that all pipes that work with "pbosh", will also work with "ksh93" but still
may fail with e.g. "bash".

If you like to check whether your script is portable to the SVr4 Bourne Shell
as present on e.g. Solaris 10, it is recommended to check whether it also
runs with another compile variant of "bosh" from schilytools called "osh".
This is a portable version of the Solaris 10 SVr5 Bourne Shell.

Note: in order to make "pbosh" halfway useful, persistent aliases are not
disabled by default. You may either test your scripts with other shells in
addition, or edit the Makefile and comment out the lines with:

```
CPPOPTS +=      -DDO_GLOBALALIASES      # Include persistent aliases in ~/.globals 
CPPOPTS +=      -DDO_LOCALALIASES       # Include persistent aliases in .locals
```

Then call "make clean all" to recompile "pbosh" with persistent aliases
disabled.