# execute command from find called by find

Tags: shell, find

Is there a way to call find recursively?

I would like to search for files matching a given pattern only in directories matching another pattern.

Basically:

```
for each (sub)directory D matching "*.data"
do
  for each file F in directory D (with subdirs) matching "*.important.txt"
  do
    run command foo on F
  done
done
```

Now, if I leave out the innermost requirement (*run command foo in F*), it is pretty simple:

```
find . -type d -name "*.data" \
     -exec find \{\} -type f -name "*.important.txt" \;
```

However, I haven't found a way to pass a command to the inner `find`.
E.g. the following prints out *find: missing argument to `-exec'* each time the inner find is called:

```
 find . -type d -name "*.data" \
      -exec find \{\} -type f -name "*.important.txt" \
                 -exec "foo \{\} \;" \;
```

Any solution should be posix compliant (runnable within a `/bin/sh` script), esp. I am not looking for solutions that

- wrap the inner find into a separate shell-script
- wrap the inner find into a bash-function

Comment: @don_crissti no it's not; but i figure a `find` calling another `find` was...

Comment: So you only need to find directories matching `*.data` and then for each file matching `*.important` in those directories (without descending) you have to run some command, right ?

Comment: How about something like `find ... | while read dir; do`?

Comment: FYI, you don't need to escape the `{}`; empty braces are not special to the shell, and quoting them doesn't change how `find` will "see" them anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run `find` on its own result, you can use the `-c` argument to `sh` (or `bash`) to prevent the outer find command from treating the inner `{}` specially. However, you then need to pass the result from the outer find as an argument to `sh`, which can be expanded with `$0`:

```
find . -type d -name "*.data" \
      -exec sh -c 'find "$0" -type f -name "*.important.txt" -exec echo \{\} \;' \{\} \;
```

Note: `$0` should be quoted (`"$0"`) to prevent issues with directory names containing whitespace.

This is not really a "recursive" solution, because it doesn't allow arbitrarily deep nesting without some hairy escaping, but it does support the two levels of `find -exec`s you asked for in your example.

If your example is similar to your actual problem, you might also experiment with the `-path` argument to find instead:

```
find . -path '*.data/*important.txt'
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `-path` would be the right choice here - depends whether  OP wants to descend (as `-path` would also match something like `.../somedir.data/another_dir/somefile.important.txt`) or not. If no recursion is needed inside those `.data` dirs then maybe something like `find . -type d -name \*.data -exec sh -c 'for f in "$0"/*.important.txt;do stuff "$f";done' {} \;` would be better.

Comment: While the pseudocode in OP's example suggests that OP wants only to operate on direct children of directories matching `*.data`, the broken attempt in OP's third code block suggests to me that files matching `*.important.txt` in all descendant subdirectories should be passed as an argument to `foo`. Both my solution and the `-path` suggestion would do this. You are correct that a simple glob would be easier if this is not required.

Comment: If you want to have more control about subdirectories than `-path` gives you  you can try `-regex`.

Comment: yes indeed, a simple globbing does not help me; i need to descend into the directories (i've updated my pseudo-code)

Answer (score 1):

**bash version (not POSIX compliant)**

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type d -name 'a *' -print0 \
    | while IFS= read -r -d '' dir ; do
        find "$dir" -type f -name "*.c" -exec echo \{\} \;
    done
```

Problems:

- [`read` has no `-d` parameter in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/read.html)
- [`find` has no `-print0`
  parameter in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html)

---

**(bad) sh version (POSIX compliant)**

```
#!/bin/sh
# WARNING: while this will work on directory names with spaces,
#          it will break on directory names that contain newlines
find . -type d -name 'a *' -print \
    | while IFS= read -r dir ; do
        find "$dir" -type f -name "*.c" -exec echo \{\} \;
    done
```

Problem: As stated in the comment, it will break on directory names containing newlines. You may think this is not a realistic issue, but this adds unnecessary fragility to your script. Maybe another program has a bug that will create such a directory, etc.

---

**(better) sh version**

see [Ian Robertson's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274927/72597)

---

Btw. if you need your scripts to be POSIX compliant, it's a good idea to use [`shellcheck`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277754/72597). For example, it will notice that `read -d` is not defined in POSIX.