# Why does this script work in the terminal but not from a file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, string

I have this shell script saved in a file:  it does some basic string substitution.

```
#!/bin/sh
html_file=$1
echo "html_file = $html_file"
substr=.pdf
pdf_file="${html_file/.html/.pdf}"
echo "pdf_file = $pdf_file"
```

If I paste it into the command line, it works fine:

```
$ html_file="/home/max/for_pauld/test_no_base64.html"
  echo "html_file = $html_file"
  substr=.pdf
  pdf_file="${html_file/.html/.pdf}"
  echo "pdf_file = $pdf_file"
```

gives

```
html_file = /home/max/for_pauld/test_no_base64.html
pdf_file = /home/max/for_pauld/test_no_base64.pdf
```

That's the output from echo above - it's working as intended.

But, when I call the script, with

```
$ saucer "/home/max/for_pauld/test_no_base64.html"
```

I get this output:

```
html_file = /home/max/for_pauld/test_no_base64.html
/home/max/bin/saucer: 5: /home/max/bin/saucer: Bad substitution
```

Is my script using a different version of bash or something?  Do I need to change my shebang line?

Comment: That parameter expansion is a bashism (well, non-POSIX) : change your shebang.

Comment: Thanks! That worked.  I think I'm a bit hazy on the difference between `sh` and `bash`.  I'll read up on it.  If you can bothered to make your comment into an answer then I will mark it correct.

Comment: Gave the tick to The Duke for his detailed answer, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @MaxWilliams: in a nutshell, sh is the original bourne shell. All compatible scripts should be written for sh. But many subsequent shells (ex: bash, Bourne Again shell) are "almost compatible" and add a lot of extra niceness. Such as the substitution you used. Nowadays, you are quite safe using only the posix features, but be aware that portability depends on even a narrower set (ie, sh only). So in general, use: `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as your shebang, and use posixly defined substitutions as you wish, but with portability caveats. And read: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48787/27616

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## What is sh

`sh` (or the Shell Command Language) is a programming language described by the [POSIX
standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html).
It has many implementations (`ksh88`, `dash`, ...). `bash` can also be
considered an implementation of `sh` (see below).

Because `sh` is a specification, not an implementation, `/bin/sh` is a symlink
(or a hard link) to an actual implementation on most POSIX systems.

## What is bash

`bash` started as an `sh`-compatible implementation (although it predates the POSIX standard by a few years), but as time passed it has acquired many extensions. Many of these extensions may change the behavior of valid POSIX shell scripts, so by itself `bash` is not a valid POSIX shell. Rather, it is a dialect of the POSIX shell language.

`bash` supports a `--posix` switch, which makes it more POSIX-compliant. It also tries to mimic POSIX if invoked as `sh`.

## sh = bash?

For a long time, `/bin/sh` used to point to `/bin/bash` on most GNU/Linux systems. As a result, it had almost become safe to ignore the difference between the two. But that started to change recently.

Some popular examples of systems where `/bin/sh` does not point to `/bin/bash` (and on some of which `/bin/bash` may not even exist) are:

1. Modern Debian and Ubuntu systems, which symlink `sh` to `dash` by default;
2. [Busybox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox), which is usually run during the Linux system boot time as part of `initramfs`. It uses the `ash` shell implementation.
3. BSDs, and in general any non-Linux systems. OpenBSD uses `pdksh`, a descendant of the Korn shell. FreeBSD's `sh` is a descendant of the original UNIX Bourne shell.  Solaris has its own `sh` which for a long time was not POSIX-compliant; a free implementation is available from the [Heirloom project](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html).

How can you find out what `/bin/sh` points to on your system?

The complication is that `/bin/sh` could be a symbolic link or a hard link.
If it's a symbolic link, a [portable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/file.html) way to resolve it is:

```
% file -h /bin/sh
/bin/sh: symbolic link to bash
```

If it's a hard link, try

```
% find -L /bin -samefile /bin/sh
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
```

In fact, the `-L` flag covers both symlinks and hardlinks,
but the disadvantage of this method is that it is not portable —
POSIX [does not require](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) `find` to support the `-samefile` option,
although both [GNU find](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Hard-Links) and [FreeBSD find](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)) support it.

## Shebang line

Ultimately, it's up to you to decide which one to use, by writing the «shebang» line.

E.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
```

will use `sh` (and whatever that happens to point to),

```
#!/bin/bash
```

will use `/bin/bash` if it's available (and fail with an error message if it's not). Of course, you can also specify another implementation, e.g.

```
#!/bin/dash
```

## Which one to use

For my own scripts, I prefer `sh` for the following reasons:

- it is standardized
- it is much simpler and easier to learn
- it is portable across POSIX systems — even if they happen not to have `bash`, they are required to have `sh`

There are advantages to using `bash` as well. Its features make programming more convenient and similar to programming in other modern programming languages. These include things like scoped local variables and arrays. Plain `sh` is a very minimalistic programming language.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer:  I use Linux Mint which is Debian-based and `/bin/sh` is indeed a symlink to `/bin/dash`.

Comment: If you want to adhere to POSIX sh, then best leave out the shebang completely: *If the first line of a file of shell commands starts with the characters "#!", the results are unspecified* http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html

Comment: @DanielJour If any Unix-like system dropped the usual support for shebangs it would break so many things it would be practically unusable. So it's a de facto standard, even if it's not specified in POSIX. The only actual compatibility issue is that the path to interpreters may differ.

Answer (score 23):

Adding to the excellent answer from @Hunter.S.Thompson I'd like to point out that the non-portable part of the script is

```
pdf_file="${html_file/.html/.pdf}"
```

The `${variable/search/replace}` is a GNU extension. But you can easily avoid it with pure POSIX:

```
pdf_file="${html_file%.html}".pdf
```

Following Hunter, this is the better fix than changing the shebang to `#! /bin/bash`

Comment: Thanks - I agree that it's the "purer" fix but I'd rather the shebang loaded bash, as bash is what I routinely use in the terminal (by default) and it's easier to have the scripts just do the same thing as the regular command line.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Of course, no problem. This was mainly indended for the Q&A database.