# Is there a test harness that can check how POSIX compliant a shell is?

Tags: shell, posix

Assuming I write a shell, is there some form of test harness that ensures that the shell is POSIX compliant (specifically `/bin/sh` without any of the bash extensions) in that it would run most constructs that `/bin/sh` supports.

This is the reverse of [How can I test for POSIX compliance of shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48786/how-can-i-test-for-posix-compliance-of-shell-scripts) in that I am looking for something like a bunch of shell scripts that are POSIX-compliant and we are just testing the shell.

Comment: There's http://www.opengroup.org/testing/testsuites/vscpcts2003.htm (and I believe there should be newer things than that) but you'd have to submit a system for certification to obtain it. Might be worth asking on the austin-group-l mailing list.

Comment: Major shell have some POSIX compability, and the developers are member of the Austin group (so POSIX standardization): you cannot imagine that many bugs of shell become discussion on that group to interpret and improve wording of POSIX standard. I doubt tests are current on the standard (it is not more a market which provide money, and so incentives) -- So, if a shell doesn't *pass* a test in compatibility mode, it is probable that the POSIX standard will change to accommodate it (but if other shell developers things differently)