# Cross Unix Command Reference

Tags: command-line, reference

I am looking for a website that contains a reference between how to do things on the command line in different unix OSs.

I have seen such site before, I am just unable to find it.

I know such site would be beneficial for the community.

Comment: Please leave comments if confused, or topic is to broad

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resources for portable shell programming](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9997/resources-for-portable-shell-programming)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Unix Rosetta Stone](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html) (resource for sysadmins) might be the one you had in mind.

Comment: By far one of the single most useful references when switching between unix OSs.

Answer (score 0):

I have a good solution:
Install 2 types of Linux OS: RedHat-base and Debian-base, FreeBSD and Solaris. Forget MacOS.
Read and work with them, of course start with Linux then hack so on.

Please refer to following sites:

- [Basic UNIX Commands, Metacharacters, & Command Line Editing](http://www.nbcs.rutgers.edu/~edseries/UNIXcmds.html)
- [OS X's BSD/unix command-line](http://www.westwind.com/reference/os-x/commandline/)
- [Basic UNIX commands](http://doors.stanford.edu/~sr/computing/basic-unix.html)

**Don't forget to consider POSIX or GNU extension, some of commands has GNU extension, some of commands are POSIX. Please read carefully.**

Comment: You copied my idea :).  Yeah I have 4 OSs installed in Virtual Machines right now.  The general commands are mostly the same.  That isn't the issue so much.  It is commands like how do I set a static ip,  where are such and such settings stored